# Is it possible to set a src attribute of an img tag in CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, src

Is it possible to set the `src` attribute value in CSS? 
In most cases, we use it like this:

```
<img src="pathTo/myImage.jpg" />
```

and I want it to be something like this

```html
<img class="myClass" />
```

```js
.myClass {
    some-src-property: url("pathTo/myImage.jpg");
}
```

I want to know if there is a way doing it **without** using the `background` or `background-image` properties in CSS.

Answer (score 1129, accepted):

Use [`content:url("image.jpg")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content).

Full working solution (<kbd>[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3BRN7/406/)</kbd>):

```html
<!doctype html>

<style>
.MyClass123{
    content:url("http://imgur.com/SZ8Cm.jpg");
}
</style>

<img class="MyClass123"/>
```

Tested and working:

- Chrome 14.0.835.163
- Safari 4.0.5
- Opera 10.6
- Firefox 100 & newer

Tested and **Not** working:

- FireFox 40.0.2 (observing Developer Network Tools, you can see that the URL loads, but the image is not displayed)
- Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17905 (URL never loads)

Comment: The content property should be used with a pseudo tag, see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp

Comment: @gotqn, only Chrome Safari Opera so far.

Comment: @EricG, different applications have different requirements. If it doesn't suit your requirements, don't use it. If it does, use it.

Comment: I think you can only use it with :after and :before

Comment: @RobAu and @mlwacosmos, no. The `content` property applies to all elements. [http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#content](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#content)

Comment: @XP1 That depends on the CSS version you use. CSS3 supports content everywhere, whereas CSS2.1 only allows :before and :after.

Comment: Unfortunately this method is useless if you are using sprites. The background-image property is still the only all-terrain solution.

Comment: Not working IE10 is a no-go. We ditch IE7 (let's not talk about IE6). IE8 too, if needed. But IE9 - IE10... no.

Comment: Doesn't work properly in every browser. See http://jsfiddle.net/krnlde/2VC4v/ for reference.

Comment: Worth to add that even in browsers that support assigning `content` to `img`, it changes its behavior. The image starts to ignore size attributes, and in Chrome/Safari it loses the context menu options like 'Save image'. This is because assigning a `content` effectively converts `img` from _empty replaced_ element to something like `<span><img></span>`.

Comment: This works for me in android 2.3 WebView and Chrome... of course

Comment: without proper browser support I don't see this as a valid answer, sorry.

Comment: FYI, there is another downside to this if you pre-set the src-attribute of the `<img>` tag with an url (e.g. for seo) and you'd like to overwrite it via css property `content:url(...)` then BOTH images will be loaded which again produces network overhead.

Comment: @Timo, which browser actually loads it twice? And assuming that is right, the overhead should be pretty low for properly cached images.

Comment: @Pacerier Missunderstanding. In my note I was talking about 2(!) different images. A low-res one for the src-attribute of the image and a high-res one for retina displays which is set via `content:url(...)`. I tested on Google Chrome and it loaded both images although only 1 would be enough.

Comment: Incredibly, this does work on Android 2.3 but it does not on Firefox 30.

Comment: @XP1: Keep in mind that that particular draft of css3-content is an abandoned draft that was last modified a decade ago at the time you posted your comment - CSS *2* has had more than a few updates since. There is a very good reason Moz/MS have not implemented it - as far as they are concerned, *that module does not exist*, and thus `content` applies *only* to `::before` and `::after`. It is being resurrected here: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-content with a big red warning that says "Not Ready For Implementation" - so I wouldn't bank on authors being able to use it cross-browser any time soon.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has linked to http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent yet. Shows the browsers supported and known issues.

Comment: @adam0101, That page doesn't show the status for `content:url("image.jpg")`. The charts there are showing all green but it still doesn't work for IE and FF.

Comment: @EricG - Because browser quirks shouldn't be the developer's problem.  If the browser doesn't respond correctly to the code, that's a problem for the people who make that browser to fix.  And if a user makes use of a browser before the browser vendor has fixed it, then that's simply user-error.  This solution solves the developer's problem.  The rest is up to the good people at Mozilla and Microsoft to fix.

Comment: @aroth I think I was just frustrated over a (for me) incomplete solution that (perhaps I) was expected to solve, ofcourse it's a good solution if it helps people.

Comment: I couldn't use the solution since it doesn't support all browsers I need. I worked out another solution that helped me (might not work for all of you, but it should work in all Css3 compatible browsers). and here it is:

I took a background-image fallback for images without src:
updated fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3BRN7/669/)

Comment: Thank you, this snippet just helped me save huge amount of $$ :) :) :)

Comment: Still does not work in Firefox 66.0.3, in case anybody was wondering, although you can still see the network request for the image.

Comment: Content property is not good for img tag. Its not valid html.

Comment: Is there a way to use this in a JSON notation? something like:

imageContent['content'] = url("imageurl.jpg")

this doesn't seem to work in react.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the images loaded via CSS `content:` will have a much lower load priority than those loaded via the `src` tag (assuming the IMG element is immediately visible). This could be useful for having your IMG elements load a lowres placeholder in their src tags, and a highres image in the CSS content. On the flipside, it could cause issues if you're completely depending on CSS `content:` to load in immediately-visible, high-priority images (such as a website logo) with no lowres placeholders.

Comment: I used this method within a media query and it works great. I tested it on chrome, firefox, edge and vivaldi.

Comment: This works hover on `:hover` it causes a flash of no image.

Comment: Hover-based demo based on your JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alanhogan/076qzp25/

Answer (score 194):

There is a solution that I found out today (works in IE6+, FF, Opera, Chrome):

```
<img src='willbehidden.png' 
 style="width:0px; height:0px; padding: 8px; background: url(newimage.png);">
```

How it works:

- The image is shrunk until no longer visible by the width & height.
- Then, you need to 'reset' the image size with padding. This
  one gives a 16x16 image. Of course you can use padding-left /
  padding-top to make rectangular images.
- Finally, the new image is put there using background.
- If the new background image is too large or too small, I recommend using `background-size` for example: `background-size:cover;` which fits your image into the allotted space.

It also works for submit-input-images, they stay clickable.

See live demo: http://www.audenaerde.org/csstricks.html#imagereplacecss

Enjoy!

Comment: @RobAnu: This works quite well - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TimPietrusky/R7gQn)

Comment: Got to hand it to you that this is fascinating and clever, but an empty DIV is more straight-forward.

Comment: In this case it is. There are cases however, where you cannot control the HTML and want to manipulate the IMG nonetheless. There this solution will also work

Comment: +1 nice suggestion. Check this modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R7gQn/4/) of the above comment.

Comment: If the image has a `src` attribute, this is the technique you need. +1 - helped me a lot

Comment: Not ranking on this answer, which might be the solution for some applications, but this method has a limitation. You have no control over the dimensions of the rendering of the image file. In normal use, you can control the height-width of an image, if the file is specified in the source. But this is basically no different from a div with a background image, where if your div is bigger than the image, you're out of luck.

Comment: In case I'm missing something, is there any reason to use this approach in a situation where you control the HTML? Perhaps this answer could be enhanced by mentioning when it makes sense to use this approach and when it makes sense to simply use an empty div.

Comment: Not really, structure wise it would make sense to use IMG for images. Or if you do not wish to change all your HTML code..

Comment: Wow, sneaky technique, which works nice when the image is hard-coded and you only have access to a css file. To target the image with css: img[src$="image.png"] ($= is ends with http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp )

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, cross browser and very nice trick !

Comment: Does not answer the op's requirement (which is the same as mine). "I don't want to use the background or background-image". This answer deserves a markdown for that (as well as the fact that a div can do this much more elegantly)

Comment: This was the perfect solution for my needs. I could not easily change the HTML and did not want to make changes to the HTML when the need to replace the image only exists on a handful pages out of thousands that are all using the same html. Great trick!

Comment: Clever, but it should be noted that this solution does not affect the results of a 'Save Image' or 'Copy Image URL' action...in those cases, you will still get the image defined in the `src` attribute.

Comment: works well. even on todays browsers

Answer (score 133):

### A collection of possible methods to set images from CSS

---

**CSS2**'s [`:after`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content) pseudo-element or the [newer](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements) syntax [`::after`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#gen-content) from **CSS3** along with the [`content:`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content) property:

<sub>First W3C Recommendation: [Cascading Style Sheets, level 2
CSS2 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/) **12 May 1998**</sub>
<sup>Latest W3C Recommendation: [Selectors Level 3
W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) **29 September 2011**</sup>

This method ***appends*** content just *after* an element's document tree content.

Note: some browsers *experimentally* render the `content` property directly over *some* element selectors disregarding even the latest W3C recommendation that defines:

> Applies to: `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements

CSS2 syntax (forward-compatible):

```css
.myClass:after {
  content: url("somepicture.jpg");
}
```

CSS3 Selector:

```css
.myClass::after {
  content: url("somepicture.jpg");
}
```

Default rendering: **Original Size** (does not depend on explicit size declaration)

> This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be defined in more detail in a future specification.

but even at the time of this writing, behaviour with a `<IMG>` tag is still not defined and although it can be used in a [hacked and non standards compliant way](http://jsfiddle.net/7kyg38bs/), ***usage with `<img>` is not recommended***!

Great candidate method, see conclusions...

---

---

**CSS1**'s [`background-image:`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1-961217#background-image) property:

<sup>First W3C Recommendation: [Cascading Style Sheets, level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1-961217) **17 Dec 1996**</sup>

> This property sets the background image of an element. When setting a background image, one should also set a background color that will be used when the image is unavailable. When the image is available, it is overlaid on top of the background color.

This property has been around from the beginning of CSS and nevertheless it deserve a glorious mention.

Default rendering: **Original Size** (cannot be scaled, only positioned)

*However*,

**CSS3**'s [`background-size:`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) property improved on it by allowing multiple scaling options:

<sup>Latest W3C Status: *Candidate Recommendation* [CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/) **9 September 2014**</sup>

> `[length> | <percentage> | auto ]{1,2} | cover | contain`

But even with this property, it depends on container size.

Still a good candidate method, see conclusions...

---

---

**CSS2**'s [`list-style:`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style) property along with `display: list-item`:

<sup>First W3C Recommendation: [Cascading Style Sheets, level 2
CSS2 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/) **12 May 1998**</sup>

`list-style-image:` property sets the image that will be used as the list item marker (bullet)

> The list properties describe basic visual formatting of lists: they allow style sheets to specify the marker type (**image**, glyph, or number)

`display: list-item` — This value causes an element (e.g., **`<li>`** in HTML) to generate a principal block box and a marker box.

```css
.myClass {
    display: list-item;
    list-style-position: inside;
    list-style-image: url("someimage.jpg");
}
```

Shorthand CSS: (`<list-style-type> <list-style-position> <list-style-image>`)

```css
.myClass {
    display: list-item;
    list-style: square inside url("someimage.jpg");
}
```

Default rendering: **Original Size** (does not depend on explicit size declaration)

Restrictions:

-

> Inheritance will transfer the 'list-style' values from OL and UL elements to LI elements. This is the recommended way to specify list style information.

- 

> They do not allow authors to specify distinct style (colors, fonts, **alignment**, etc.) for the list marker or adjust its **position**

This method is also not suitable for the `<img>` tag as the conversion cannot be made between element types, and here's the [limited, non compliant hack](http://jsfiddle.net/3BRN7/552/) that doesn't work on Chrome.

Good candidate method, see conclusions...

---

---

**CSS3**'s [`border-image:`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images) property *recommendation*:

<sup>Latest W3C Status: *Candidate Recommendation* [CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/) **9 September 2014**</sup>

A *background-type* method that relies on specifying sizes in a rather peculiar manner *(not defined for this use case)* and fallback border properties *so far* (eg. `border: solid`):

> Note that, even though they never cause a scrolling mechanism, outset
> images may still be clipped by an ancestor or by the viewport.

This example illustrates the image being *composed* only as a bottom-right corner ***decoration***:

```css
.myClass {
    border: solid;
    border-width: 0 480px 320px 0;
    border-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/uKnMvyp.jpg") 0 100% 100% 0;
}
```

> Applies to: All elements, except internal table elements when `border-collapse: collapse`

Still it can't *change* an `<img>`'s tag `src` (but [here's a hack](http://jsfiddle.net/d2vuftjv/)), instead we can decorate it:

```css
.myClass {
    border: solid;
    border-width: 0 96px 96px 0;
    border-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Christmas_bell_icon_1.png") 
                  0 100% 100% 0;
}
```

```html
<img width="300" height="120" 
     src="http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2012/253/b/0/merry_christmas_card_by_designworldwide-d5e9746.jpg" 
     class="myClass"
```

Good candidate method to be considered after standards propagate.

---

---

**CSS3**'s [`element()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css4-images/#element-notation) notation *working draft* is worth a mention also:

> Note: The `element()` function only reproduces the *appearance* of the referenced element, not the actual content and its structure.

```
<div id="img1"></div>

<img id="pic1" src="http://i.imgur.com/uKnMvyp.jpg" class="hide" alt="wolf">
<img id="pic2" src="http://i.imgur.com/TOUfCfL.jpg" class="hide" alt="cat">
```

We'll use the *rendered contents* of one of the two *hidden images* to change the image *background* in `#img1` based on the ***ID Selector*** via CSS:

```css
#img1 {
    width: 480px; 
    height: 320px; 
    background: -moz-element(#pic1) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.hide {display: none}
```

Notes: It's ***experimental*** and only works with the `-moz` prefix in Firefox and only over `background` or `background-image` properties, also needs sizes specified.

- [element() Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gpjmt7s6/)

---

## Conclusions

1. Any semantic content or structural information goes in HTML.
2. Styling and presentational information goes in CSS.
3. For SEO purposes, don't *hide* meaningful images in CSS.
4. Background graphics are usually disabled when printing.
5. [Custom tags](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Custom_Tags_Analysis) could be used and styled from CSS, but *primitive* versions of Internet Explorer do not understand]([IE not styling HTML5 tags (with shiv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602758/ie-not-styling-html5-tags-with-shiv)) without Javascript or CSS *guidance*.
6. SPA's (Single Page Applications), by design, usually incorporate images in the background

Having said that, let's explore HTML tags fit for image display:

#### The [`<li>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-li-element) element [HTML4.01+]

Perfect usecase of the **`list-style-image`** with `display: list-item` method.

The `<li>` element, can be empty, allows [flow content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content-2) and it's even permitted to omit the `</li>` end tag.

```css
.bulletPics > li {display: list-item}
#img1 {list-style: square inside url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Nuvola_erotic.png")}
#img2 {list-style: square inside url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/Globe_icon_2014-06-26_22-09.png")}
#img3 {list-style: square inside url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Kiwi_fruit.jpg")}
```

```html
<ul class="bulletPics">
    <li id="img1">movie</li>
    <li id="img2">earth</li>
    <li id="img3">kiwi</li>
</ul>
```

Limitations: hard to style (`width:` or `float:` might help)

#### The [`<figure>`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/figure) element [HTML5+]

> The figure element represents some flow content, optionally with a caption, that is self-contained (like a complete sentence) and is typically referenced as a single unit from the main flow of the document.

The element is valid with no content, but is recommended to contain a `<figcaption>`.

> The element can thus be used to annotate ***illustrations, diagrams, photos***, code listings, etc.

Default rendering: the element is right aligned, with both left and right padding!

- [FIGURE Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3BRN7/542/)

#### The [`<object>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html) element [HTML4+]

> To include images, authors may use the OBJECT element or the IMG element.

The `data` attribute is required and can have a valid [MIME type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.1) as a value!

```
<object data="data:x-image/x,"></object>
```

Note: a trick to make use of the `<object>` tag from CSS would be to set a  *custom* valid MimeType `x-image/x` followed by no data (value has no data after the required comma `,`)

Default rendering: 300 x 150px, but size can be specified either in HTML or CSS.

- [OBJECT Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3BRN7/546/)

#### The [`<SVG>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction) tag

Needs a SVG [capable browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) and has a  [`<image>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElement) element for raster images

- [SVG Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zzgum41k/)

#### The [`<canvas>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) element [HTML5+].

> The `width` attribute defaults to **300**, and the `height` attribute defaults to **150**.

- [CANVAS Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9czfoosk/)

#### The `<input>` element with `type="image"`

Limitations:

> ... the element is expected to appear button-like to indicate that the element is a button.

which Chrome follows and renders a 4x4px empty square when no text

Partial solution, set `value=" "`:

```
<input type="image" id="img1" value=" ">
```

- [INPUT type=image Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhm4y7da/1/)

---

Also watch out for the upcoming [`<picture>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/semantics.html#the-picture-element) element in **HTML5.1**, currently a *working draft*.

Comment: (2020) Use CSS properties: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/is-it-possible-to-set-the-equivalent-of-a-src-attribute-of-an-img-tag-in-css/60673253#60673253

Comment: Great answer but shows the complete failure of the web as a platform to provide basic primitives.

Answer (score 26):

i used the empty div solution, with this CSS:

```
#throbber {
    background-image: url(/Content/pictures/ajax-loader.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    min-width: 48px;
    min-height: 48px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="throbber"></div>
```

Comment: What if I want to display it inline? Adding "display: inline" gives my div dimension of 0x0...

Comment: @elsurudo Use display:inline-block if you want to set a width and height on an inline element

Comment: The top answer doesn't work with Firefox, so I like your answer more! And it is clear and have no css hacks.

Comment: If you need to display more than one image, bear in mind the id field is technically supposed to be unique, so using a CSS class selector instead of the ID is ideal.

Comment: Images of this type won't print properly if you have background graphics turned off in print settings.

Answer (score 15):

I found a better way than the proposed solutions, but it does use the background-image indeed.
*Compliant method (cannot confirm for IE6)* 
Credits: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/lir/

```
<img src="pathTo/myImage.jpg"/>
```

The CSS:

```
img[src*="pathTo/myImage.jpg"] {

    background-image: url("mynewimg.jpg"); /* lets say 20x20 */
    width: 20px;

    display:inline-block;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    height: 0px !important;

    /* for IE 5.5's bad box model */
    height /**/:20px;
}
```

The old image is not seen and the new is seen as expected.

*The following neat solution only works for webkit*

```
img[src*="pathTo/myImage.jpg"] {

    /* note :) */
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url("mynewimg.jpg"); /* lets say 20x20 */

}
```

Comment: This is a neat trick, but is it really standards compliant? The [W3C page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-content) says the `content` property only applies to the `:before` and `:after` pseudo classes. Also, if you have to support IE7 or earlier, I think `content` support is non-existent. Still, very tempting.

Comment: You are right, I just found a more compliant method. Updating my post! Now vote me up ;) Haha.

Comment: The updated approach is definitely better than the one relying on content. Thanks for including the original link. That was insightful. You'll note that @RobAu's answer is actually very similar to your updated version as well.

Comment: @jatrim The `content` property applies to all elements. [http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#content](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#content)

Answer (score 13):

Here is a very good solution -> http://css-tricks.com/replace-the-image-in-an-img-with-css/

Pro(s) and Con(s):
 
(+) works with vector image that have relative width/height (a thing that [RobAu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461499/robau)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/how-can-we-specify-src-attribute-of-img-tag-in-css/10247567#10247567) does not handle)
 
(+) is cross browser (works also for IE8+)
(+) it only uses CSS. So no need to modify the img src (or if you do not have access/do not want to change the already existing img src attribute).
(-) sorry, it **does use** the background css attribute :)

Comment: Now, that's the proper solution, works for me in all browsers, thanks!! Also worth to mention I had to add: background-size: 100%; to css class in solution above to make replacement image show properly.

Answer (score 12):

No you can't set the image src attribute via CSS. The closest you can get is, as you say, `background` or `background-image`. I wouldn't recommend doing that anyway as it would be somewhat illogical.

However, there is a CSS3 solution available to you, if the browsers you're targeting are able to use it. Use `content:url` [as described in Pacerier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/how-can-we-specify-src-attribute-of-img-tag-in-css/11484688#11484688). You can find other, cross-browser solutions in the other answers below.

Comment: why the down vote? this answer is more accurate than the accepted answer.

Comment: The best answer so far : NO, you can't do it with CSS.

Answer (score 12):

They are right. IMG is a content element and CSS is about design.
But, how about when you use some content elements or properties for design purposes?
I have IMG across my web pages that must change if i change the style (the CSS).

Well this is a solution for defining IMG presentation (no really the image) in CSS style.

1. create a 1x1 transparent gif or png.
2. Assign propery "src" of IMG to that image.
3. Define final presentation with "background-image" in the CSS style.

It works like a charm :)

Comment: -1 Even though your answer isn't bad, he specifically mentions that he doesn't want to use `background*`

Comment: this is a trick... in my opinion tricks will be changed by browsers... and a day at morning you'll see a hell in your website :D :)))

Answer (score 9):

You can define 2 images in your HTML code and use `display: none;` to decide which one will be visible.

Comment: I was searching far and wide for a solution that was Web Responsive but also maintained SEO. I wanted to use media queries in CSS to change my image depending on the device used, but I wanted to keep my content in HTML. Declaring sources in CSS was a route I did not want to take, so `background-image` was not an option. I wanted `img` tags for SEO purposes. Your answer is so simple, elegant, and solves all my hurdles! bravo! Also user doesn't have to download both images. Furthermore, I can add any number of images.

Comment: Every answer I read so far would force me to either declare my sources in my stylesheet, or use inline CSS in my markup. Neither of which I was pleased with. Messy code!

Answer (score 5):

Or you could do this which I found on the interweb thingy.

https://robau.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/override-image-src-in-css/

```
<img src="linkToImage.jpg" class="egg">
```

```css
.egg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0 0 200px 0;
  background-image: url(linkToImage.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

So effectively hiding the image and padding down the background.  Oh what a hack  but if you want an IMG tag with alt text and a background that can scale without using JavaScript?

In a project I'm working on now I created a hero block twig template

```
<div class="hero">
  <img class="image" src="{{ bgImageSrc }}"
       alt="{{ altText }}" style="background-image: url({{ bgImageSrc }});">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Put several images in a "controlling" container, and change the container's class instead. In CSS, add rules to manage images' visibility depending on the container's class. This will produce the same effect as changing `img src` property of a a single image.

HTML:

```
<span id="light" class="red">
    <img class="red" src="red.png" />
    <img class="yellow" src="yellow.png" />
    <img class="green" src="green.png" />
</span>
```

CSS:

```
#light         { ... }
#light         *        { display: none; }     // all images are hidden
#light.red     .red     { display: inline; }   // show red image when #light is red
#light.yellow  .yellow  { display: inline; }   // .. or yellow
#light.green   .green   { display: inline; }   // .. or green
```

Note that it will preload all images, like with CSS `backround-image`s, but unlike changing `img src` via JS.

Answer (score 4):

Some data I would leave in HTML, but it is better to define the **src** in CSS:

```
<img alt="Test Alt text" title="Title text" class="logo">

.logo {
    content:url('../images/logo.png');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative way

```
.myClass {
background: url('/img/loading_big.gif');
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware of, YOU CANNOT. CSS is about style and image's src is content.

Comment: Nowadays, quite often images are there just to style up the page.

Comment: The implication is that there may be a difference between images used as borders, backgrounds etc. and those that are actually part of the page content ie. diagrams, article photos etc.

Comment: YOU CAN, and there are common, valid cases where you would want to.

Answer (score 2):

To reiterate a prior solution and to stress the pure CSS implementation here is my answer.

A Pure CSS solution is needed in cases where you are sourcing content from another site, and thus you have no control over the HTML that is delivered.  In my case I am trying to remove branding of licensed source content so that the licencee does not have to advertise for the company they are buying the content from.  Therefore, I'm removing their logo while keeping everything else.  I should note that this is within my client's contract to do so.

```
{ /* image size is 204x30 */
     width:0;
     height:0;
     padding-left:102px;
     padding-right:102px;
     padding-top:15px;
     padding-bottom:15px;
     background-image:url(http://sthstest/Style%20Library/StThomas/images/rhn_nav_logo2.gif);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a really old question however no answers provide the proper reasoning for why this can never be done.  While you can "do" what you are looking for you cannot do it in a valid way.  In order to have a valid img tag it **must** have the src and alt attributes.

So any of the answers giving a way to do this with an img tag that does not use the src attribute are promoting use of invalid code.

In short: what you are looking for cannot be done legally within the structure of the syntax.

Source: W3 Validator

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to set a background property then you can't set the src attribute of an image using only CSS.

Alternatively you can use JavaScript to do such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS, it **can't** be done. But, if you are using JQuery, something like this will do the trick:

```
$("img.myClass").attr("src", "http://somwhere");
```

Comment: actually, it can )) see the answer on this same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/how-can-we-specify-src-attribute-of-img-tag-in-css/19114098#19114098

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it with JS:

```
$('.image-class').each(function(){
    var processing = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).parent().css({'background-image':'url('+processing+')'});
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add an image in a button dynamically based on the context of your project, you can use the ? take to reference the source based on an outcome.  Here I am using mvvm design to let my Model.Phases[0] value determine whether I want my button to be populated with images of a lightbulb on or off based on the value of the light phase.

Not sure if this helps.  I'm using JqueryUI, Blueprint, and CSS.  The class definition should allow you to style the button based on whatever you'd like.

```
    <button>                           
  <img class="@(Model.Phases[0] ? "light-on": "light-off")" src="@(Model.Phases[0] ? "~/Images/LightBulbOn.png" : "~/Images/LightBulbOff.png")"/>                             
  <img class="@(Model.Phases[0] ? "light-on": "light-off")" src="@(Model.Phases[0] ? "~/Images/LightBulbOn.png" : "~/Images/LightBulbOff.png")"/>   
  <img class="@(Model.Phases[0] ? "light-on": "light-off")" src="@(Model.Phases[0] ? "~/Images/LightBulbOn.png" : "~/Images/LightBulbOff.png")"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add this: background image could be also positioned with `background-position: x y;` (x horizontal y vertical). (..)
My case, CSS:

```
(..) 
#header {
  height: 100px; 
  background-image: url(http://.../head6.jpg); 
  background-position: center; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-color: grey; 
  (..)
} 
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

HTMl Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
         <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css destination" />
     </head>
     <body>
<!-- click-able pic with link -->
           <a href="site you want"> 
<!-- Take the off if you don't want click-able link -->
                <h1 id(or class)="nameOfClassorid">
                     <span>Text that is not important</span>
                </h1>
           </a>
      </body>
 </html>
```

Css Code:

```
span {
     display: none;
}
h1 id or class {
     height: of pic;
     width: of pic;
/* Only flaw (so far) read bottom */
     background-image:url(/* "image destination" */);
}
h1 id or class:hover {
/* Now the awesome part */
     background-image:url(/* 'new background!!!' */);
}
```

I've been studying html after school for a few days, and wanted to know how to do this. Found out the background and then put 2 and 2 together.
This works 100% I checked, if not make sure you fill in necessary things!!!
We need to specify height, because without it there would be nothing!!!
I'll leave this basic shell you can add-on.

Example:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
         <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
     </head>
     <body>
           <a href="http:localhost"> 
                <h1>
                     <span>Text that is not important</span>
                </h1>
           </a>
     </body>
 </html>
span {
     display: none;
}
h1 {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
     background-image:url("http://linuxlog.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Ubuntu-Desktop-@-2011-01-11-191526-300x225.png");
}

h1:hover {
     height: 300px;
     width: 300px;
     background-image:url("http://cdn.css-tricks.com/images/ads/wufoo-600x600-red.png");
}
```

P.S. Yes I am a Linux user ;)

Answer (score 0):

Any method based on `background` or `background-image` is likely to fail when user prints the document with *"print **background** colors and **images**"* disabled.
Which is unfortunately typical browser's default.

The only print-friendly and cross-browser compatible method here is the one proposed by Bronx.

Answer (score -1):

Just use HTML5 :)

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="smaller.jpg" media="(max-width: 768px)">
    <source srcset="default.jpg">
    <img srcset="default.jpg" alt="My default image">
</picture>
```

Comment: The OP is specifically looking to clean up their HTML markup with a CSS solution. This answer would only further clutter the markup.