# Weird White Image Border W/logo

Tags: html, css

I am trying to load an image using css styling and I have a red ridge border around it, but for some reason when I use css instead of html I get a odd small white border on the inside of the red ridge border with a white logo in the top left hand corner the little logo could be a tiny monitor I don't know how else to describe it. Does anyone know what is going on? I have other images loaded the same way with no problem.

Here is the CSS script

```
        html

            <table class="TopTableLeft">
        <tr class="TopTableLeft">
          <th class="thTopTableLeft1"><div class="tblheadr">&nbsp;&nbsp;Symbol&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></th>            
          <th class="thTopTableLeft2"><div class="tblheadr2">Meaning</div></th>
    </tr>
        <tr> 
      <td class="ntscheduled"></td> 
          <td class="tdtext">Not Scheduled</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td class="astris"></td>
          <td class="tdtext">&nbsp;&nbsp;Deactivated Tanks&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td class="bltest"></td>
      <td class="tdtext">Test Scheduled</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
      <td class="grntest"></td>
          <td class="tdtext">Test In Process</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
      <td class="rdtest"></td>
          <td class="tdtext">Test Late</td>
        </tr>
   </table>
<div id="pic" align="center" style="float:left;">
  <img class="logo"/>
</div>
<div id="toptable2" align="center" style="float:none;">
   <table class="TopTableRight">
        <tr class="TopTableRight">
          <th class="thTopTableRight1"><div class="tblheadr2">Meaning<div/></th>
          <th class="thTopTableRight2"><div class="tblheadr"">&nbsp;&nbsp;Symbol&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></th>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
      <td class="tdtext">Not Scheduled</td>
          <td class="ntscheduled"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td class="tdtext">&nbsp;&nbsp;Deactivated Tanks&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="astris"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tdtext">Test Scheduled</td>
          <td class="bltest"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td class="tdtext">Test In Process</td>
          <td class="grntest"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td class="tdtext">Test Late</td>
          <td class="rdtest"></td>
        </TR>
  </table>

              css




    table.TopTableLeft{
    float:left; border:5px; border-style:outset; border-color:#FFFF00; 
    height:20px; width:23%; border-spacing:0; border-collapes:collapse;
}

    table.TopTableRight{
    float:right;border:5px; border-style:outset;border-color:#E80000; height:20px; 
    width:23%; border-spacing:0; border-collapes:collapse; vertical-align:top;
}

    tr.TopTableLeft{
    background-color:#595959;color:FFFF00;
}

    tr.TopTableRight{
    background-color:#595959;color:FFFF00;
}

    th.thTopTableLeft1{
    border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:45;height:20;
}

    th.thTopTableLeft2{
    border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:125;height:20;
}

    th.thTopTableRight1{
    border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:125;height:20;
}

    th.thTopTableRight2{
    border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:45;height:20;
}

    div.tblheadr{
    text-align:center; margin-bottom:-1px;
}

    div.tblheadr2{
    text-align:center; margin-bottom:-1px;
}

            td.tdtext{
            background-color:#000000; color:#FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; 
            font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;
    }

    td.ntscheduled{
    background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;
    background-image: url(../Images/Not-Scheduled.png); background-size:22px 24px; 
    width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;
}

    td.astris{
    background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;
    background-image: url(../Images/Gray-Astris3.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; 
    height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;
}

    td.bltest{
    background-color:#000000;color:#FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;
    background-image: url(../Images/Blue-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; 
    height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;
}

    td.grntest{
    background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;
    background-image: url(../Images/Green-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:22;
    height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;
}

    td.rdtest{
    background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;
    background-image: url(../Images/Red-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:22; 
    height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;
}

    img.logo{
    float:none; margin-left:120px; margin-right:auto; margin-top:17px; 
    border:10px ridge #E80000; background-image: url(../Images/Logo.png); 
    background-size:199px 101px; width:199; height:101; background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-position:center;
}
```

Comment: Can you add yout HTML or create a FIDDLE?

Comment: @AnaMaria I added the html that loads the picture.

Comment: Do you have a live link or a jsFiddle link to the issue?

Comment: Ok i created a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/57T8S/ IS this what you see?

Comment: @AnaMariaThat's the logo I see in the top left hand corner. It is a black logo so that logo there shows up in the top left hand corner and then because the logo is black there is a white border on the inside of the red border

Comment: @chrisw.iec - Dont make us imagine your issue. Provide a screenshot with what you want and what is happening right now.

Comment: @chrisw.iec your beating me all black & blue. can you take some time and describe your problem a bit better

Comment: Change your element tag from <img> to <div> or anything else

Comment: @chrisw.iec, you need to add more code. Unless we understand your issue perfectly, we cant give a perfect solution

Comment: @AnaMaria Sorry for beating you black and blue, but I thought I had the logo you see in the jsfiddle is not the logo I want loaded what you see in the fiddle is a logo that is on top of the image I want loaded it is in the upper left hand corner and and there is a white border on the inside of the 10px red ridge border that should not be there.

Comment: I think you got your answer with aayushi's solution

Comment: @anamaria That just changed the size in fiddle I think it has something to do with the tag, but if I use div the alignment of thre tables goes wacky thanks though.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/8F8RT/ - @chrisw.iec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your soution:

```
img.logo {
      margin-left:120px;
      margin-right:auto;
      margin-top:17px;
      border:10px ridge #E80000;
      background-image: url(../Images/Logo.png);
      background-size:199px 101px;
      width:199px;
      height:101px;
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-position:center;
  }
```

Check out the Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57T8S/2/)

Width and Height must be defined in `px`

**Edit:**

Move your `img` tag in `div` like

```
 <div id="logo"><img/></div>
```

and then add its CSS:

```
#logo{
    float:none; 
    margin-left:120px; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    margin-top:17px; 
    border:10px ridge #E80000; 
    background-color: blue; 
    background-image:  url(../Images/Logo.png);
    background-size:199px 101px;
    width:199px;
    height:101px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Here is the working Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwhGR/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation! :)

Comment: well that changes the size in the fiddle wasn't a problem in IE 10, but the logo that comes up in fiddle is still superimposed over my original image in the top left hand corner and there is a white border on the inside of the red border. I think the img tag is the issue.

Comment: `<img class="logo" src="~/Images/Logo.png"/>` That is an obvious HTML Solution. OP wants it by CSS.

Comment: what is that white thing in the upper left hand corner? Can't you see it?

Comment: @AayusjiJain I removed the end </img> tag and it worked thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your html is the problem. You have image with no source specified, but you put background instead. Browser is trying to read image but can't find source. Use image source and remove background or use span for example and leave background.

Comment: He did specify an image (on the background).

Comment: using image scr works that's what I had before changing to css I was just trying to get rid of as much info in html and adding it all to css. thanks your answer is correct

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775469/whats-the-valid-way-to-include-an-image-with-no-src
Using img src in html and background-image in css are 2 different things, so I'm sticking with my previous answer.