# Valid HTML5 and img src-attribute on AngularJs ng-src

Tags: html, image, angularjs, src

Anyone has idea, how to produce valid HTML5 when images are displayed with AngularJs ng-scr directive?

What I have discovered?

- "src"- attribute is required on img-tags
- It can't be empty
- Console reports 404 error if I set src attribute data with angular binding, cause it tries to load image before Angular has initialized

Why I want valid HTML?

Reason is simple. Strange HTML errors (missing end tags, open tags etc..) causes strange behavior in our project where we have LOTS of views. Ensuring periodically that source is valid, makes code less unstable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775469/whats-the-valid-way-to-include-an-image-with-no-src/5775621#5775621) stems a genious hack:

`<img ng-src="modelImage" src="//:0">`

...much easier to remember from the top of your head than an image URL ;)

ngSrc:  any string which can contain {{}} markup.

Comment: This fails w3c validator: Bad value //:0 for attribute src on element img: Invalid host: empty host.

Comment: @Damjan: You can use `src="#"`.

Comment: @chliebel - `#` will cause some browser trigger pointless network requests (which is really much worse than just losing w3c validity imho), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775469/whats-the-valid-way-to-include-an-image-with-no-src/5775621#answer-28077004

Comment: @Philzen Actually depends on your acceptance criteria.