# How can I replace/substitute an attribute name, not its content

Tags: jquery, attributes

On my site, each post starts with an image:

```
<img src="sample.jpg" alt="sample alt" />
```

and what I'm looking for is to change all image entries to:

```
<img data-src="sample.jpg" alt="sample alt" />
```

So basically I want to either:

- Append/prefix `src` with `data-`

or

- Replace/substitute `src` with `data-src`

I've looked at `.replace()` `.replaceWith()` `.before()` `.insertBefore()` and none of them did what I wanted.

A bit of info on why I want to do this. I want to implement unveil.js (lazyload) and one of the requirements is to include the actual image source in a "data-src" attribute. I don't want to mix html with markdown, hence this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best that can be done is

```
$('img[src]').attr('data-src', function(){
    return $(this).attr('src')
}).removeAttr('src');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9f9C9/)

Comment: I'm trying this out, when you say the best that can be done, are there any other, more simplified method of doing it?

Comment: @Aqeel not as far as I know

Comment: if you're dealing with each element on it'S own (as @Felix does in his answer), you can get rid of the closure as argument to `attr`. Instead you have the `.each()` and a closure inside that one of course - not sure which one is simpler.

Comment: technically, you solution loops as well, just inside jQuery. there really isn'T too much difference, technically, between both answers. Non should be more efficient or anything. It's just how they look - I think Felix' one is a little easier to get. Personal preference for sure.

Comment: And now another dilemma, both solutions work fine, which one do I check mark on?

Comment: @Aqeel for fairness I'd say the one without the two upvotes ;)

Comment: @Aqeel both are the same... I think it is upto what you prefer

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$('img').each(function(i, el){
    $(el).attr('data-src', $(el).attr('src')).removeAttr('src');
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mtQ99/)**

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
$('img').each(function( index ){
    $(this).data('src', $(this).attr('src')).removeAttr( "src" );
});
```

Reverse also works

```
$('img').each(function( index ){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('src')).removeData( "src" );
});
```

Comment: this doesn't remove the "old" attribute.

Comment: the author doesn't mention removal

Comment: no, but "substitution", which is "remove one and add another one instead".

Comment: I have to agree with @JohannesH. the before and after code is clear as to what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer in regard to your question but also to your scenario of use.

You're using unveil.js to boost performance but the method you're using does the opposite. This method is actually [invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775469/whats-the-valid-way-to-include-an-image-with-no-src)

use the [smallest gif](http://probablyprogramming.com/2009/03/15/the-tiniest-gif-ever) image as your src and then use the data-src with the actual image src.

If you do it the way you're presenting there is no use of unveil.js since the browser will pull the image right away before even using/initiallizing unveil.js.

Suggestions (two scenarios):

1) SERVER HTML
   - change all images to use the method above directly on the sever. When your content is downloaded on the browser initialize unveil.js and let it do its job.

2) AJAX GET REQUEST (HTML OR JSON)
  - if you get your content with ajax, before your inject it and while it is still in the form of a string you can apply a regex such as: postContent.replace(/src=/gi, "data-src=") in order to replace every occurrence of src= to data-src=. After injecting your content to the dom, execute the unveil.js init function.