# .error inside .click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing some testing with working and broken images:

HTML:

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://asdf.com/working.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://asdf.com/broken.jpg" /></a> <!-- non valid URL -->
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).find('img').error(function() {
      alert('Image does not exist!');
    });
    return false;
});
```

This works to an extent... Basically I want it to alert ONLY if the user clicks on the broken image. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The [error event](http://api.jquery.com/error/) might have already fired before you click the link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977871/check-if-an-image-is-loaded-no-errors-in-javascript/1977898#1977898

Answer (score 0):

I would bind to the image for error events, then add the alert logic if there was an error.
Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejobkgsw/) example I created.

```
$( "img" ).error(function() {
  $( this ).click(function() { 
    alert('Image does not exist!'); 
  });
});
```

Comment: That still assumes that the handler is bound before the `error` event fires. Which afair can be even before DOMContentLoaded.

Answer (score 0):

The `error()` method was deprecated in jQuery 1.8.  So you should be using `on('error',function(){});` instead.  But, you still have the issue where the error handler has to be attached before the image load is attempted.  So, you can set the img src after you attach the handler.

EDIT:  It was bothering me that I didn't have a src in my img tag (invalid HTML), so I found this inspired stack overflow: [What's the valid way to include an image with no src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775469/whats-the-valid-way-to-include-an-image-with-no-src).  The `src="//:0"` is from there.

HTML:

```
<a href="#"><img data-src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" src="//:0" /></a>

<a href="#"><img data-src="http://asdf.com/broken.jpg" src="//:0" /></a> 
<!-- non valid URL -->
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').on ('error', function () {
        $(this).data('error',true);
    }).each(function() {
        $(this).attr('src',$(this).data('src'));
    });
    $('a').click(function () {
        if($(this).find('img').data('error') == true) alert('Image does not exist!');
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/10xjo3of/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `onerror` attribute for images. the following compatibility table lists the browsers that support the `onerror` attribute and you can see that you can use this without any issue:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/error.html

Add `onerror="$(this).addClass('error');"` to images like this:

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://asdf.com/working.jpg" onerror="$(this).addClass('error');" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://asdf.com/broken.jpg" onerror="$(this).addClass('error');" /></a> <!-- non valid URL -->
```

And on every click, check the `error` class:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    if ($(this).find('img').hasClass('error')){
        alert('Image does not exist!');
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rgkxao9f/1/)**