# Google chrome v41 , <img> tag with min-height is not recognized?

Tags: css, image, google-chrome

There is an issue with tag `<img>` on `Google Chrome` (mac/windows) `version 41` (or > `v40.x`)

**Html**

```
<img src="">
```

**Css**

```
img{
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-width: 570px;
    border: 3px dashed #ddd;
    color: #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I do not remember perfectly what was the version, but I'm sure it was the 40.x, and the result was this

[image]

Now the same css, with version 41, does not work as it should. The square is not displayed

[Test on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h4wvjLg7/1/)

> I would need a solution even if it worked only on Google Chrome, my
>   project must run only on Google Chrome, thanks.

Comment: The img need to have an `src` to be displayed, try with a random src like `blank.gif`

Comment: @Hacketo , that solution has always worked, only with the latest versions of Google Chrome no longer works

Comment: This might have been deliberate change on Chrome's part. Having an empty `src` in general is never a good thing. Can result in bad commands, different browsers would treat it differently.

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775469/whats-the-valid-way-to-include-an-image-with-no-src

Comment: @Hacketo , this works `<img src="//:0">`