# Img src from hex color?

Tags: html, image

I need to add some alt text and/or titles to some image tags on a webpage.

The html structure is not really in my control, so image tags are required even though the tags themselves are being set to display a flat colour derived from a hex-code stored in a SQL table.

**Like This**

`<img style="background-color:{@hexCode};" title="{@colourName}"/>`

With `@hexCode` being the colour code in question (i.e. '#1f1f1f') and `@colourName` being the descriptive name for the colour chosen by the client.

The problem I'm having is that because the colour is being set by the `background-color`property the title text (and alt text does this too) is being displayed on top of the colour as well as on hover.

[image: Titles should not be visible here]

Google has not given me any useful solutions and I can't just not add the titles to the images? What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the valid way to include an image with no src?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775469/whats-the-valid-way-to-include-an-image-with-no-src)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `div`s instead. The reason that the `title` or `alt` is showing up is because they are supposed to be displayed if the image is not found, and you are not giving a `src`.

```html
<div style="background-color: gold; height: 30px; width: 30px;" title="Gold"></div>
```

However, if you must use an `img` tag with no source you can use `src="//:0"` to fake a valid source.

```html
<img src="//:0" style="background-color: gold; height: 30px; width: 30px;" title="Gold" />
```

Comment: He said `The html structure is not really in my control`

Comment: @animeshmanglik I must have skipped over that part. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Nothing is holy in this question... D:

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I'm having is that because `the colour is being set by the
>   background-color property` the title text (and alt text does this too)
>   is being displayed on top of the colour as well as on hover.

No - The title and alt text is being displayed because your image is not loaded, precisely why they are used.
https://jsfiddle.net/b0njy0gg/

When an image source is present https://jsfiddle.net/thajo9pL/

Answer (score 0):

I assume since you're defining `img` tags without a `src` attribute, SEO isn't one of your goals - if that's the case, the following solution of setting the `font-size` of your image to 0 will also affect the rendering of the alt text rendering, as you can see in this example:

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img alt="Test" />
```

For anyone concerned about w3c validity or SEO-friendlyness: Do not try this at home!