# How to define custom attributes for HTML 4.01 Strict DocType

Tags: html, doctype

I'd like to add custom attributes to the `<div>` tags in my HTML.  Is there a way to append those variables to the Doctype description, or should I not even worry about it.  I found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/how-can-we-specify-src-attribute-of-img-tag-in-css) on StackOverflow, but it addressed XHTML.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? why does it need custom attributes?

Comment: No need to do so as far as I am aware. After all it is not standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own DTD, but not sure how some browsers might react to it, so you will have to test.

http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/own-dtd.html

edit: overall it depends on what you are doing. It's best if you can avoid a modified dtd.

.. I had to find it, but once I did something like this to get past validation (using propietary code, and couldn't change much at the time, but wanted to get it as close to valid as possible)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd" [
<!ATTLIST DIV
    something     CDATA        #IMPLIED
>
]>
```

if there was something in the code like:

```
<div something="nothing"></div>
```

And I wasn't allowed to change it.

The problem is that you can't leave it in the page, because it will probably print out the "]>", but it works for defining an extra attribute for a validator.

Comment: Browsers do not care about DTDs. They only care about doctype declarations as strings, for the purposes of selecting Quirks vs. “standards” mode, and any customized doctype triggers “standards” mode.