# Change image of img tag on hover using CSS

Tags: css, image, html-table

I have a image menu. I want to change the `image` into `TD` table when the link is activated.

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <a href="http://pinkmodels.16mb.com/">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/jO3ni.jpg">
            </a>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <a href="http://pinkmodels.16mb.com/models/">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/utKcC.jpg">
            </a>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <a href="http://pinkmodels.16mb.com/blog/">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/h4JGE.jpg">
            </a>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <a href="http://pinkmodels.16mb.com/about/">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/M2GE8.jpg">
            </a>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <a href="http://pinkmodels.16mb.com/contact/">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bWoe3.jpg">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Before anyone gets worried about the content at the other end of these links, there's nothing bad there. It's PG rated.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using `<img>` tags use `background-image` property in your CSS file.

For example,

```
table td a{
    display: block;
    background-image:url('FirstImageURL');
    /* other background properties like "background-size", if needed */
}

table td a:active{
    background-image:url('SecondImageURL');
}
```

**or else**

You can change the image using [**content**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) css property:  (*works in chrome*)

```
.className { /* or "img" */
    content:url('ImagePathURL');
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/MzP2X/4/).

The above you can do by assigning unique classes (or Id's) to each `img` tag. or else using `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors in combination with `+`(*sibling*) selector. Something like this:

```
table > img:first-child{ /* css properties */ }                     /* first  child */
table > img:first-child + img{ /* css properties */ }               /* second child */
table > img:first-child + img + img { /* css properties */ }        /* third  child */
table > img:first-child + img + img + img { /* css properties */ }  /* fourth child */
table > img:last-child { /* css properties */ }                     /* fifth  child */
```

For more information check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2182716/1577396).

I hope you know CSS because you haven't used anywhere in your code :)

Answer (score 2):

```
a:visited img ,a:active img
{
content:url('change img link as you want);
}
```

Comment: but i have individual images for every single button

Answer (score 0):

Two choices:

### JavaScript solution:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var n = links.length;
for(var i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    var cur = links[i];
    if(cur.getAttribute("href") == window.location) {
        cur.parentNode.childNodes[1].src = "http://i.imgur.com/newimagesrc.png";
    }
}
```

### CSS-only solution:

Instead of using an `img` tag, use a `div` with a `background-image`, HTML would look like:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="left"><a href="http://pinkmodels.16mb.com/">
            <div class = "image first"></div>
        </a></td>
```

CSS:

```
a:active > .image.first {
     background-image: url(newimageurl.png);
}
```