# Is it possible to change img src attribute using css?

Tags: css, image, src

I'm trying to change img src (not the background img src) with css

```
<img id="btnUp" src="img/btnUp.png" alt="btnUp"/>  

#btnUp{
    cursor:pointer;
}
#btnUp:hover{
    src:img/btnUpHover; /* is this possible ? It would be so elegant way.*/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - CSS can only be used to change CSS background images, not HTML content.

In general UI elements (not content) should be rendered using CSS backgrounds anyway. Swapping classes can swap  background images.

Comment: Wrong - You can easily do this with CSS3 and the `content` attribute, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/how-can-we-specify-src-attribute-of-img-tag-in-css#answer-11484688

Comment: Update: the content attribute only works in Webkit/Chrome - Not in FF or IE.

Comment: CSS is better, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832129/replace-image-src-location-using-css
and detail here: https://css-tricks.com/replace-the-image-in-an-img-with-css/

Comment: This is a wrong answer. You can set the image using the content property in CSS as noted by @gjgsoftware.com

Comment: Osify has the answer in his second link

Answer (score 33):

You can use :

```
content: url("/_layouts/images/GEARS_AN.GIF")
```

Comment: Update: Seems like this only works in webkit/Chrome but not in FF or IE.

Comment: 2021 Update: `content: ` is now widely supported across pretty much all browsers. See: https://caniuse.com/css-gencontent

Comment: @SamuelGfeller The context of the question implies applicability _outside_ of pseudo-elements, i.e. using `content` directly on an `<img>` tag. Your link only applies to pseudo-elements (like `::before` and `::after`) -- and Firefox still adheres to the standard here, while Chrome does not.

Comment: Right! Is that a more relevant link? https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_content
Btw here is the `content:` property used in a similar context than OPs question https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content#element_replacement.

Answer (score 18):

There is another way to fix this : using CSS box-sizing.

HTML :

```
<img class="banner" src="http://domaine.com/banner.png">
```

CSS :

```
.banner {
  display: block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(http://domain2.com/newbanner.png) no-repeat;
  width: 180px; /* Width of new image */
  height: 236px; /* Height of new image */
  padding-left: 180px; /* Equal to width of new image */
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/replace-the-image-in-an-img-with-css/

Comment: this was handy for me

Comment: happy that can help

Comment: @qadenza 

This is not the right solution. This changed the background image. The question asked talks about the main image. So you need to use `content` to do the job. Like below:


`img.nav-logo {
    content: url('/Logo.png');
}`

Answer (score 5):

you could try something like this

```
<img id="btnUp" src="empty.png" alt="btnUp" />
```

or

```
<div id="btnUp" title="btnUp"> <div/>
```

---

```
#btnUp{
    cursor:pointer;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;       
}

#btnUp{
    background-image:url('x.png')
}

#btnUp:hover{
    background-image:url('y.png')
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS to a) make the original image invisible by setting its width and height to 0, or moving it off-screen etc, and b) insert a new image in its ::before or ::after pseudo-element.

That will be a performance hit though, as the browser will then load both the original and the new image. But it won't require Javascript!

Answer (score 3):

You can't set the image `src` attribute via CSS. you can get is, as if you wanted to set use `background` or `background-image`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mixture of JavaScript and CSS to achieve this, but you can not do this with CSS alone. `<img id="btnUp" src="empty.png" alt="btnUp" onmouseover="change(img)" onmouseout="changeback(img)" />`
Instead of img you would put file name sans file type.

```
function change(img){
document.getElementById("btnUp").src= img + ".png";
}
function changeback(img){
document.getElementById("btnUp").src= img + ".png";
}
```

Then you use CSS to modify the img tag or the id to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the image to a completely transparent image, then change the background image like so:

```
img {
background-image: url("img1.png");
}
//For example, if you hover over it.
img:hover {
background-image: url("img2.png");
}
```

The images do have to be the same size though. :(
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`content:url('imagelinkhere');`

This is working, I tested it