# Replace image src location using CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I have a website that has an image with a src attribute and I would like to change the src location of that image with an image of my own. The image lives in a div component. I can't change the HTML and am looking ways to change it using CSS only please.

**Div component**:

```
<div class="application-title">
<img style="margin-top: 3px;height: 45px;" src="image.svgz">
</div>
```

**Image component(CSS file)**:

```
.application-title IMG
{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You may not have access to the HTML...but do you have access to the image file? Why not just overwrite the image with the new one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set the equivalent of a src attribute of an img tag in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/is-it-possible-to-set-the-equivalent-of-a-src-attribute-of-an-img-tag-in-css)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use a background image

```css
.application-title img {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding-left: 200px;
  /*width of the image*/
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city/2) left top no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="application-title">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city/1/">
</div><br />
Original Image: <br />

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city/1/">
```

Comment: Man, you won't believe. I just found that solution myself. Its the box -sizing and padding that would make it work instantaneously.

Comment: Saw this link and I was like.. booya!
https://css-tricks.com/replace-the-image-in-an-img-with-css/

Answer (score 22):

Here is another dirty hack :)

```
.application-title > img {
display: none;
}

.application-title::before {
content: url(path/example.jpg);
}
```

Comment: This is the closest solution, but it's not possible to side the image.

Answer (score 17):

you can use: `content:url("image.jpg")`

```
<style>
.your-class-name{
    content: url("http://imgur.com/SZ8Cm.jpg");
}
</style>

<img class="your-class-name" src="..."/>
```

Comment: can you please clarify how to add local url path ?  <img class="grow-together-component__bottom-img" src="./images/bg-section-bottom-mobile-1.svg"
        alt="bottom design">, I want to change to something else from "./images/.." but it is not working

Comment: This should be the starred answer. It directly replaces the image URL as you really want, without offset hacks or other messiness. Can also use other content (like plain text). IOW it's fab.

Comment: @tekHedd I agree. The [browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/?search=content) is also great.

Answer (score 5):

You could do this but it is hacky

```
.application-title {
   background:url("/path/to/image.png");
   /* set these dims according to your image size */
   width:500px;
   height:500px;
}

.application-title img {
   display:none;
}
```

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/5tbxkzzc/

Comment: I have added a jsfiddle. Had to add width and height, but it does work.