# Javascript - Override input content

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using Google Custom Search and it displays the following code when I open the page's source code:

```
<input type="image" src="https://www.google.com/uds/css/v2/search_box_icon.png" class="gsc-search-button gsc-search-button-v2" title="search">
```

The problem is that I don't have direct access to that code, since it's retrieved by javascript.

I tried using:

```
 gsc-search-button gsc-search-button-v2 {
 background: url("pathtofile");
}
```

To change the input icon, but all it gonna do is changing the background of the container. I need to change the source image, but since I don't have direct access to the HTML, how can I use javascript to achieve that?

Comment: `.gsc-search-button-v2 {}`

Comment: `$('.gsc-search-button.gsc-search-button-v2').attr('src','foo.png');`

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/28832129/561731

Comment: @Neal Funny how I've already tried all of those options, yet you say it's a duplicate. Please, don't complicate things.