# How to change source of <img> tag on hover?

Tags: html, css

I need to change `<img>` source URL on `hover`.

I have tried this but won't work :

HTML

```
<img id="my-img" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff"/>
```

CSS

```
#my-img:hover {
    content: url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff');
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ec9gn/)

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

This only works for Webkit / Google Chrome.

Comment: `content` only works with `:before` or `:after` so this is not going to work. Why not use a `div` with a background image and onhover change that background image?

Comment: I don't want to use `DIV`.

Comment: I don't believe that you can change the source attribute with CSS only. jQuery or normal JavaScript are good candidates to do that simple.... and I agree with @putvande, the `content:` only works with `:before` or `:after`

Comment: Well... you can set the background image of the `img` tag and just remove the `src` from your image. Although that is a bit strange, it will work. @HamedKamrava: You can only use an image or can you use something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we specify src attribute of img tag in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/how-can-we-specify-src-attribute-of-img-tag-in-css)

Comment: I think it's possible using `content:` in hover, the code should work but actually `:hover` doesn't trigger in this situation. It seems to be not working for `<img>`

Comment: Use anchor tag or other wise use Javascript code for change the img src onhover. Which is explained in my below post

Comment: This only doesn't work for CSS2. In CSS3 your solution should work perfectly because there is no need for `:before` or `:after` pseudo classes to use `content:url(...)`. Update: This only works for Webkit / Google Chrome.

Comment: Any way to get this working in FireFox ?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

With only html and css, its not posible to change the src of image. If you do replace the img tag with div tag, then you might be able to change the image that is set as the background as like

```
div {
    background: url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff');
}
div:hover {
    background: url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff');
}
```

And if you think you can use some javascript code then you should be able to change the src of the img tag as below

```js
function hover(element) {
  element.setAttribute('src', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff');
}

function unhover(element) {
  element.setAttribute('src', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff');
}
```

```html
<img id="my-img" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);" />
```

Comment: In addition, if you use the CSS option, in case you do not want the image to 'flicker' into view while it needs to load on hover, you can preload it on your page by putting it somewhere hidden: `<img src="..." style="visibility: hidden" />`

Answer (score 135):

I have modified few changes related to Patrick Kostjens.

```
<a href="#">
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/angry-birds/128/yellow-bird-icon.png" 
onmouseover="this.src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/angry-birds/128/red-bird-icon.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/angry-birds/128/yellow-bird-icon.png'"
border="0" alt=""/></a>
```

DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/ssuryar/wcmHu/429/

Comment: The Console and Network does not show any activity. The only way I can understand this happening is because it is cashed and that this is a simple and a valid answer.

Comment: You can also replace the "this" by "document.getElementById" or class, in order to target another img src.

Comment: Thank you ! Such a very simple and compact solution saved my day ! I have been searching the whole web for hours and I could just find messy solutions based on CSS and which only worked partially. This works GREAT ! Thanks again ! Of course I simply had to replace '#' with my link and the url of the images

Answer (score 41):

Here is an alternate approach using pure CSS. The idea is to include both the images in the HTML markup and have these displayed or hidden accordingly on :hover

**HTML**

```
<a>
   <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/imoticons/105/imoticon_15-128.png" /> 
   <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/imoticons/105/imoticon_12-128.png" />
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a img:last-child {
  display: none;  
}
a:hover img:last-child {
  display: block;  
}
a:hover img:first-child {
  display: none;  
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m4v1onyL/

Note that the images used are of the same dimensions for proper display. Also, these images file sizes are quite small so loading multiple is not an issue in this case but may be if you are looking to toggle display of large sized images.

Comment: @putvande the approach may be similar but this is a complete and simplified working example that makes better use of CSS selectors

Comment: This solution also allows you to still make use of the srcset attribute of img, needed for crisp images on retina displays.

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar problem but my solution was to have two images, one hidden (display:none) and one visible.  On the hover over a surrounding span, the original image changes to display:none and the other image to display:block.  (Might use 'inline' instead depending on your circumstances)

This example uses two span tags instead of images so you can see the result when running it here.  I didn't have any online image sources to use unfortunately.

```css
#onhover {
  display: none;
}
#surround:hover span[id="initial"] {
  display: none;
}
#surround:hover span[id="onhover"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span id="surround">
    <span id="initial">original</span>
    <span id="onhover">replacement</span>
</span>
```

Comment: FYI, you can say `span#initial` in place of `span[id="initial"]`

Answer (score 16):

What you could do is cheat a little bit by setting `width` and `height` to 0 to hide the actual image and apply some CSS to do what you want:

```
#aks {
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    background:url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff');
    padding:50px;
}

#aks:hover {
    background: url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff');
}
```

And the padding making the `img` tag the size you want it to have (half the size of your actual image).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ec9gn/22/)

Comment: why would you do this over using a DIV?

Answer (score 12):

Concerning semantics, I do not like any solution given so far. Therefore, I personally use the following solution:

```css
.img-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg);
}

.img-wrapper > img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.img-wrapper > img:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" alt="image" />
</div>
```

This is a CSS only solution with good browser compatibility. It makes use of an image wrapper that has a background which is initially hidden by the image itself. On hover, the image is hidden through the opacity, hence the background image becomes visible. This way, one does not have an empty wrapper but a real image in the markup code.

Answer (score 6):

I have one more solution. If anybody uses AngularJs :
    http://jsfiddle.net/ec9gn/30/

```
<div ng-controller='ctrl'>
    <img ng-mouseover="img='eb00eb'"  ng-mouseleave="img='000'"
         ng-src='http://dummyimage.com/100x100/{{img}}/fff' />
</div>
```

The Javascript :

```
function ctrl($scope){
    $scope.img= '000';
}
```

No CSS ^^.

Comment: If OP doesn't want Javascript, it's hardly likely that a solution using a JS framework is relevant right?

Comment: Even better (if nobody minds using Angular for this): http://jsfiddle.net/ec9gn/420/ (added ng-init and removed controller completely).

Comment: good answer .... i just used ng-init="img=''" without the need to declare $scope.img

Answer (score 4):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kKLKC/28/)

**Agree with AshisKumar's answer, 
there is a way to change image url on mouse over by using jQuery functionality as below:**

```
$(function() {
  $("img")
    .mouseover(function() { 
        var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "over.gif";
        $(this).attr("src", url1); //URL @the time of mouse over on image
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("over", "");
        $(this).attr("src", url2); //default URL
    });
 });
```

Comment: @Naveen And how using `a` with `display:block` differs from div? Topic starter wanted to change `src` attribute of `img` through `css` and not some walkaround.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem - I want to replace picture on :hover but can't use BACKGRUND-IMAGE due to lack of Bootstrap's adaptive design.

If you like me only want to change the picture on :hover (but not insist of change SRC for the certain image tag) you can do something like this - it's CSS-only solution.

HTML:

```
<li>
  <img src="/picts/doctors/SmallGray/Zharkova_smallgrey.jpg">
  <img class="hoverPhoto" src="/picts/doctors/Small/Zharkova_small.jpg">
</li>
```

CSS:

```
li { position: relative; overflow: hidden; }
li img.hoverPhoto {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
li.hover img { /* it's optional - for nicer transition effect */
  opacity: 0;
  -web-kit-transition:  opacity 1s ease;
  -moz-transition:  opacity 1s ease;li 
  -o-transition:    opacity 1s ease;
  transition:   opacity 1s ease;
}
li.hover img.hoverPhoto { opacity: 1; }
```

If you want IE7-compatible code you may hide/show :HOVER image by positioning not by opacity.

Answer (score 3):

Since you can't change the `src` with CSS: If jQuery is an option for you, check this fiddle.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/9Q4Qe/)

```
$('#aks').hover(
    function(){
      $(this).attr('src','http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff')
    },
    function(){
      $(this).attr('src','http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff')
    }
)
```

It's basically using the `.hover()` method... it takes two functions to make it work. When you enter the hover and when you exit it.

We are using the `.attr` (short for attribute) to change the `src` attribute.

It's worth to note that you need the jQuery library included like in the fiddle to make this work.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the img src using css. You can use the following pure css solution though. 
HTML:

```
<div id="asks"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#asks {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/0000/fff');
}

#asks:hover {
  background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff');
}
```

Or, if you don't want to use a div with a background image, you can use a javascript/jQuery solution. 
Html:

```
<img id="asks" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('#asks')
  .mouseenter(function(){$('#asks').attr('src', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff');})
  .mouseleave(function(){$('#asks').attr('src', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff');});
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would go with one of the JavaScript / jQuery solutions. Not only does this keep your HTML semantic (i.e., an image is shown as an img element with it's usual src image defined in the markup), but if you use a JS / jQuery solution then you will also be able to use the JS / jQuery to *preload* your hover image.

Preloading the hover image will mean there is likely to be no download delay when the user hovers over the original image, resulting in your site behaving much more professionally.

It does mean you have a dependency on JS, but the tiny minority that don't have JS enabled are probably not going to be too fussed - and everyone else will get a better experience... and your code will be good, too!

Answer (score 1):

You can't change `img` tag's `src` attribute using `CSS`.  Possible using **Javascript** `onmouseover()` event handler.

**HTML:**

```
<img id="my-img" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" onmouseover='hover()'/>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function hover() {
  document.getElementById("my-img").src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff";
}
```

Comment: This function works, but when user moves his mouse away from the image, image doesn't change back to original image. Can you help write that code? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use below code

1) html

```
<div id = "aks">

</div>
```

2) css

```
#aks
    {
        width:100px;
height:100px;    

        background-image:url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff');}

#aks:hover {
    background-image:url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

On older browsers, `:hover` only worked on `<a>` elements.  So you'd have to do something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/ec9gn/78/) to get it to work.

```
<style>
a#aks
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
}

a#aks:link
{
  background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff');
}

a#aks:hover
{
  background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff');
}
</style>

<a href="#" id="aks"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code works at both Chrome and Firefox

```
<a href="#"><img src="me-more-smile.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='me-thinking-about-a-date.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='me-more-smile.jpg'" border="0" alt=""/></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code.

```css
   .card {

            width: 200px;

            height: 195px;

            position: relative;

            display: inline-block;

        }

        .card .img-top {

            display: none;

            position: absolute;

            top: 0;

            left: 0;
           
            z-index: 99;
width:200px;
        }

        .card:hover .img-top {

            display: inline;

        }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">

    <head>

    <title>Image Change on Hover with CSS</title>

 
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="card">

            <img src="http://www.dhresource.com/200x200s/f2-albu-g5-M00-EC-97-rBVaJFkAobCAHD9XAADvz9DDocA266.jpg/diy-wall-stickers-home-decor-nature-colorful.jpg" alt="Card Back" style="width:200px">

            <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/31/17/98/3117987a0be0a7d8976869aabf54d2d7.jpg" class="img-top" alt="Card Front">

        </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: source: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=css-image-swap-on-hover

Answer (score 1):

You can use `content: url()` in `img:hover` as below

```css
img:hover{
 content: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfS5s.gif");
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfS5s.gif?s=256&g=1" width="100px" alt="vinod">
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a pure CSS solution.  Put the visible image in the img tag, put the second image as a background in the css, then hide the image on hover.

```
.buttons{
width:90%;
margin-left:5%;
margin-right:5%;
margin-top:2%;
}
.buttons ul{}   
.buttons ul li{
display:inline-block;
width:22%;
margin:1%;
position:relative;
}
.buttons ul li a p{
position:absolute;
top:40%;
text-align:center;
}   
.but1{
background:url('scales.jpg') center no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
.but1 a:hover img{
visibility:hidden;
}   
.but2{
background:url('scales.jpg') center no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
.but2 a:hover img{
visibility:hidden;
}   
.but3{
background:url('scales.jpg') center no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
.but3 a:hover img{
visibility:hidden;
}   
.but4{
background:url('scales.jpg') center no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}   
.but4 a:hover img{
visibility:hidden;
}           

<div class='buttons'>
<ul>
<li class='but1'><a href='#'><img src='scalesb.jpg' height='300' width='300' alt='' /><p>Blog</p></a></li>
<li class='but2'><a href='#'><img src='scalesb.jpg' height='300' width='300' alt='' /> <p>Herrero</p></a></li>
<li class='but3'><a href='#'><img src='scalesb.jpg' height='300' width='300' alt='' /><p>Loftin</p></a></li>
<li class='but4'><a href='#'><img src='scalesb.jpg' height='300' width='300' alt='' /><p>Contact</p></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to change `src` for image is:

```
<img src='willbehidden.png' style="width:0px; height:0px; padding: 8px; background: url(newimage.png);">
```

See live demo: http://www.audenaerde.org/csstricks.html#imagereplacecss

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

**There is another simple way using HTML and CSS only!**
Just wrap your `<img>` tag with div like so:

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff">
</div>
```

Then, in your CSS file hide the img and set the background image for the wrapping div element:

```
.image-wrapper:hover {
    background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.image-wrapper:hover img {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Heres a simple and best solution to change src of image**

```
<img src="PATH" onMouseOver="this.src='PATH'" onMouseOut="this.src='PATH'" />
```