# Change the src of an image on mouse over

Tags: jquery, html

How can i change the src attribute like in www.mysupermarket.com  ?
On changing category, the src attribute is resetting to a default value.
Like on hovering to a subcategory the img src is changing to  src value.

Comment: You have many places to find this answer as this seems to be the basic of all the ones. Please search and then post it as a question when you don't find any answers.

Comment: html-css solution:

see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032220/css-change-image-src-on-imghover

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking as you have not provided enough information, let alone any of your `CODE!`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! (1) Please search for similar questions and answers before posting your own. (2) Please *always* provide sample code of what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

User [.hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method.

```
$('#myImg').hover(function(){
  $(this).attr("src", "images/myImage.jpg");
});
```

Comment: When i access a new category menu, the category image is the same as previous. Is not resetting the image.

Comment: Please add your code in your post itself along with html and if possible then probably add it here as well http://jsfiddle.net