# access <img> tag with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some help with CSS. I am trying to create a tree with lots of `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. The problem is that I have many `<li>` tags with a particular class, and inside that list I have an `<img>` tag.

How can I access that `<img>` tag and put different background image? I am confused how to point my `<img>` tag with the class of the `<li>` and then set a background-image.

Note: CSS3 is not allowed

---

```
<ul>
  <li class="leaf"><img></li>
  <li class="leafhidden"><img></li>
  <li class="leafhidden"><img></li>
</ul>
```

---

Thank You

Comment: Wait, you want to set a background-image on an img? Why not just use the li to set the background-image?

Comment: i must have had a long day, i didnt even notice this lol

Comment: Like this? http://cssdesk.com/WjYfD

Comment: You can't set image source through css. If you're using <img> as a background,  then I suggest you to use DIV with background-image css property

Answer (score 1):

This code will go inside .leaf and look for the img tag, then change the picture:

```
.leaf img:hover {
    content:url('http://rookery.s3.amazonaws.com/941000/941430_96b2_625x1000.jpg');
}
```

I made a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/3DXD2/

Comment: The [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) attribute and the [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) are both from CSS 2 which enjoys [rather broad support](http://caniuse.com/css-sel2). More importantly it is the right tool for this job.

Comment: @user3307470 `content is part of css3` It's a part of CSS Level 2. In fact `content` property for the `img` is only working on Webkit / Google Chrome. similar topic on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032220/css-change-image-src-on-imghover

Comment: @user3307470 Why don't you want to use CSS3? It is a very useful update of CSS. Many good features.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li.leaf img {background:url(/images/img.jpg);}    
ul li.leafhidden img {background:url(/images/img2.jpg);}
```

Comment: Sir I think it should be background-image, but still not working

Comment: doesn't need to be background-image, background has shorthand code so it will work like that. It's not working because you are giving img a background image.. take the images out, define width and height on li, and give background images to the li's

Comment: remove img from your markup and assign the li's the background image

Comment: no Sir... i need this to do this kind of codeing..really need ur help

Answer (score 0):

Use a descendant combinator.

```
.leaf img {
    background-image: url('leaf.png');
}
```

This won't do anything visible unless the image is translucent.

---

That said, it looks like you are trying to specify content images using CSS. Don't do that. Use a `src` attribute (and add an appropriate `alt` attribute).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get this to work with CSS using `background` on the `img` is the following:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YDrW7/2/)**

```
.leaf > img {
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/200/200) no-repeat;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Because the `img` and `li` tags are both empty, nothing will show up when a `background` is declared to either of them. So you have to specify a width and height.

Answer (score -1):

As simple as that:

```
ul li img { /*do your styling here*/ }
```

Edit:

Missed a point about classes:

```
ul li.leaf img { /*do your styling here*/ }
```

Comment: he wanted to know how to declare children of different classes

Comment: how to put image inside the img tag...with css

Comment: Don't think it is possible. Why can't you use `<img src=""...`?