# how to change an image to another image when hover

Tags: image, hover

How can i change an image to another image when hover?
I have image and i have to change the image to another image when mouseover. How can i do that?

Presently, I have image 1 and i have to change the image 1 to image 2 when mouseover on image 1.
And i don't know how to do that. I know how to change colors with hover but i don't know how to change it to another image.

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:1050px; left:360px;"><img src="image1.jpg"><div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing image on hover with css/html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813299/changing-image-on-hover-with-css-html)

Comment: This might help .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032220/css-change-image-src-on-imghover

Answer (score 1):

FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/rpku6d89/3/

```
<div class="hello">

</div>
```

css

```
.hello{  
    background-image: url("http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4005/4706825697_c0367e6dee_b.jpg");    
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
}
.hello:hover{
    background-image: url("http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4017/4717107886_dcc1270a65_b.jpg");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="image1.jpg" 
onmouseover="this.src='image2.jpg'" 
onmouseout="this.src='image1.jpg'">
```