# CSS: How to do image change on rollover

Tags: css, image

I am trying to do a image change when the mouse rolls over the image, but I have to use CSS not java script. I got the image to show up, but it shows up behind the first image, it doesn't replace it.

```
<a href="http://google.com"><img id="rollover" src="cat.jpg" width="250" height="188" alt="Cat"></a>

#rollover:hover {background-image: url(dog.jpg);} 
img {padding: 5px;}
```

Comment: can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23733994/861487

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: Change image src on img:hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032220/css-change-image-src-on-imghover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `img` tag.
Use the `a` itself:

```css
a
{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 188px;
    background: red;
} 
a:hover
{
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the first image via CSS also.

```
<a href="http://google.com"><div id="rollover" width="250" height="188"></div></a>

#rollover {
  background-image: url(cat.jpg);
}

#rollover:hover {
  background-image: url(dog.jpg);
}
```

Comment: What type of element did you use? ``img``, ``div`` or other?

Answer (score 0):

You could have two images and switch display property [example](http://jsfiddle.net/chepe263/fakh2exd/)

```css
    #dog{
        display: none;
        }
    #cambio:hover > #cat{
        display: none;
    }
    
    #cambio:hover > #dog{
        display:block;
        
    }
```

```html
   <a href="#" id="cambio">
        <input type="button" id="dog" value="Perro" />
        <input type="button" id="cat" value="Gato" />
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need anotehr element of A...

```
<a href="http://google.com" id="rollover"> </a>

#rollover {   background-image: url(cat.jpg); 
     width: 250px; height: 188px; 
     display: block;
}
#rollover:hover {   background-image: url(dog.jpg);  }
```

Comment: here my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alemarch/7vn10zx2/
I used background-color and border, but its the same..