# I Want to Change Images Using Hover

Tags: hover

I've been coding my portfolio website from scratch and I want to implement an image change (black and white to color) when I hover over the thumbnails in my gallery. Is there a way to do this easily? I have 14 images, two pictures each (color and black and white).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can save some traffic for you and your visitors and only have one color image, which you can desaturate using [CSS filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

Assign the class to your image in HTML: `<img class="image-bw" src="image.jpeg"/>`

Make your image black and white in non-hovered state by using this CSS:

```
.image-bw {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

And turn off this filter in hovered state:

```
.image-bw:hover {
    -webkit-filter: none;
    filter: none;   
}
```

Take into account that this solution will not work in IE. Refer [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) for detailed browser compatibility information. You may also use SVG images, which can be desaturated in IE, as described [here](http://demosthenes.info/blog/532/Convert-Images-To-Black-And-White-With-CSS).

If you want to use two images, several ways to do so are described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032220/css-change-image-src-on-imghover).