# change image src onMouseOver

Tags: css, angularjs

HTML:

```
<span class="btn-cover">
  <img src="../assets/images/btn_page_back_normal.png"  onmouseover="../assets/images/btn_page_back_normal.png" class="date-left" >
</span>
```

I have not been able to give a hover effect on the img tag is working to try to substitute a different image from angular.js.

I like what the problem is because you need the help of others, does not work.

Comment: Follow Link which i have mentioned

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813299/changing-image-on-hover-with-css-html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032220/css-change-image-src-on-imghover

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to set the src of the image to the new one

```
<span class="btn-cover">
  <img src="../assets/images/btn_page_back_normal.png"  
  onmouseover="this.src='../assets/images/btn_page_back_normal.png'" 
onmouseout="this.src='../assets/images/btn_page_back_normal.png'" 
class="date-left" >
</span>
```

**Demo**:

```html
<span class="btn-cover">
  <img src="https://www.ricoh.com/r_dc/r/r8/img/sample_08.jpg"  
  onmouseover="this.src='http://www.scanseri.fi/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/sample.jpg'" 
onmouseout="this.src='https://www.ricoh.com/r_dc/r/r8/img/sample_08.jpg'" 
class="date-left" height="100" width="100">
</span>
```

Comment: glad it helped you, vote up and accept as an answer so that it could help others as well @bismute :)

Comment: @bismute see demo also :)