# How to change (image source) in input type tags on hover with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, forms, input, src

I want to change the image src on hover with javascript, but here is the twist
Here is my HTML

```
<div class="foo">
 <div class="foo-2">
   <form>
    <input type="image" src="I want to change this on hover">
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I reviewed the ansewr of this question [CSS: Change image src on img:hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032220/css-change-image-src-on-imghover)

here is a quote of the answer:
"
 And if you think you can use some javascript code then you should be able to change the src of the img tag as below

```
function hover(element) {
element.setAttribute('src', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff');
}
function unhover(element) {
element.setAttribute('src', 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff');
}
```

and the html be

```
img id="my-img" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff"         onmouseover="hover(this);" onmouseout="unhover(this);" />
```

It is helpful, but I'm really having trouble targeting the type image in my code, so that I can change it with javascrit.

Comment: Wouldn't you just find the input and change its `src` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think changing source on hover is such a great idea. why? the images need to load and they can take relative long time to load and confuse the user if nothing happens within the 1. second.

it'd be better if you pre-load both images and then use css to hide/show the correct image on hover. this way it will show instantly.