# Change image src on hover using URL as ID

Tags: jquery, css, image, hover

I am trying to change an image src on hover.

I would like to ID an image by its URL or alt text because I cannot add a class in this circumstance.

I have tried the instructions from this Stack Overflow link with no luck:

[CSS: Change image src on img:hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032220/css-change-image-src-on-imghover)

WHen hovering over the URL of this image:

https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5463b725e4b06d233c3a876a/t/56a921809cadb641f7ce1a09/1453912583654/Screen+Shot+2016-01-27+at+8.34.20+AM.png?format=750w

I would like it to change to this image:

(I have a link for this image, but I cannot use more than two links in my post)

Here is the URL to my page:

https://toby-thiermann.squarespace.com/new-index/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the best approach for something like this is to not use an  tag and instead use CSS. Using the background-image approach and adding it to your div will then allow you to swap out the image.

Try something like this:

```
<div class="your-class-here"></div>
```

and then css like this:

```
.your-class-here{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("your-non-hover-image")
  transition: all ease 250ms
}
.your-class-here:hover{
  background-image: url("your-hover-image")
}
```

I added a transition, this just makes it a little smoother.