# How can i change image source on hover with only CSS

Tags: html

How can i change image source on hover with only CSS

i tried but was able to find only answers with javascript.

this is my code:

```
<img src="">
```

i want to change image to 1.gif when user mouse hover it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: Change image src on img:hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032220/css-change-image-src-on-imghover)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can target the image first. and then from there when user mouser over the image you can change src attribute

1. target image.

```
const img = document.getElementById('imgId');
```

2. make mouser over event like this

```
img.addEventListener('mouserover', callback);
```

3. then you make your own function like this

```
function callback(event) {
    if (img.src=== '1.gif') {
       img.src = '2.gif';
    }
}
```

4. return the 1.gif image when the mouseout

```
img.addEventListener("mouseout", anotherCallback);

function anotherCallback(event) {
    if (img.src !== "1.gif") {
        img.src = '1.gif';
    } 
}
```