# Change color of transparent image on hover using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, hover, transparent

I am trying to change the a logo image (transparent png) from white to red with CSS. I do not know any JS, only html and CSS.

I have tried using css hover with color but it doesn't work. I used background-color, which works, but I don't want the background of the image to be red. I've searched but I don't think my search description is very good.

This is the html:

```
<body>
<div class="background-container">
<header>


<a href="index.html"><img src="images/ReLiveLogoWHITE TRANSPARENT.png" class="logo"></a>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

and the css:

```
    .logo {
     height: 30vh;
     margin: 1em;


     }

     .logo:hover {
     color: red;
     }
```

I can't upload the actual image so I'll upload a royalty free image. I want to color the planet red or blue or whichever color I want, on hover. The image also acts as the home button.

[transparent image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34ydJ.jpg)

Comment: You cannot change the color of an image with css. However, you can change directly the source on hover or you can use a `svg` version of your image and then change the `fill` color with css. You can see more [here for the first method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032220/css-change-image-src-on-imghover) and [here for the second one](https://css-tricks.com/change-color-of-svg-on-hover/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that using javascript or if you just want use css follow the steps as follow:

Add the new coloured image for the hover state:

```
<a href="index.html">
   <img src="images/ReLiveLogoWHITE TRANSPARENT.png" class="logo">
   <img src="images/redImage.png" class="logo-hover">
</a>
```

Apply those styles to the CSS:

```
A .logo {
   height: 30vh;
   margin: 1em;
   display: block;
}

A:hover .logo {
   display: none;
}

A .logo-hover {
   display:none;
}

A:hover .logo-hover {
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: This method worked and was easiest for me to do with my limited experience, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with CSS filters buut they exact numbers will require some trial and error.

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20vw;
  margin: 2vh;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block
}

img:hover {
  filter: invert(50%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(290deg) saturate(500%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3999/clipart365150.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the logo html to

```
<a class="logo" href="index.html">
  <img src="images/ReLiveLogoWHITE TRANSPARENT.png" alt="">
</a>
```

and then use this css

```
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 30vh;
  margin: 1em;
}
.logo:hover {
  background-color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.logo img {
  border: 0;
}
```