# How to put a GIF when hovering the image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, gif

Hello guys I really need your help.
I am a beginner in web development and recently I started making my first website using html, css i js. I want to put 2 images that will be hyperlinks in the center of the page (one on the left and one on the right). I want my GIFs to appear when i hover these two images(GIF starts when i hover over the image and ends when I unhover it). Also the GIFs will have text overlay and some other hover animations.
Anything that can help me?
[here is the prototype(sketch)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nl3Cu.jpg)
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider sharing your code and explain what didn't work for you, so that others can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that will help you achieve your goal.
You can also check it on codepen:https://codepen.io/assar777/pen/jOMbpeP

```
 <style>
    #image{
    background-image:url('https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/image-human-brain_99433-298.jpg');
    height:400px;
    max-width:400px;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    }
    #image:hover{
    background-image:url('https://media.emailonacid.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/2019-GifsInEmail.gif');
    }
    </style>
    
    <div id="image"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, i will try and let you know.

Comment: You are welcome, If you need anything, I am here.

Answer (score 0):

if it could be done!!

You can do it with CSS itself for example:

```
.classeOfMyImage{
 background: url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff');
}
.classeOfMyImage:hover {
 background: url('https://media.tenor.com/images/1fe5b893dd6eb6905c4efabb103e6281/tenor.gif');
}
```

(I don't know how to link to another post because I'm new but they talk about it here [CSS: Change image src on img:hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032220/css-change-image-src-on-imghover))