# FF and IE don't load img src from CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, browser

I'm setting the src for an image with css like this

```
#Banner {
content: url(../Banners/prussia-awesomeness.gif);
width: 1000px;
}
```

here's my image

```
   <div id="Header" class="Header">
        <img id="Banner" src="as"/>
    </div>
```

the image loads in google chrome with the proper img src (../Banners/prussia-awesomeness.gif)

in internet explorer and firefox it keeps the src "as".

Does ie and ff not support loading image sources from css?

EDIT:

adding

```
#Banner:after {
content: url(../Banners/prussia-awesomeness.gif);
width: 1000px;
}
```

made it work in firefox, ie however still refuses to cooperate.

also tried adding :before (with : and ::), which made no difference in any browser

Comment: FF and IE do work. open Firebug in FF and click on the 'NET' tab and see what is loading. Check it is indeed the correct path.

Comment: ie and ff does not load the src from the css. the img keeps "as" as the src. My question is why it does not load in ie and ff when it does in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that CSS content property doesn't work for IMG but other elements for IE & Safari. Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3TYZ/1/) Fiddle. For Safari check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-content) out.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Header" class="Header">
        <img id="Banner1" src="as"/>
    <h1 id="Banner">test</h1>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#Banner:before {
content: url(http://w3c.org/2008/site/images/favicon.ico);
width: 1000px;
}
#Banner1:before {
content: url(http://w3c.org/2008/site/images/favicon.ico);
width: 1000px;
}
```

It may not work with IE8 if you don't have DOCTYPE! specified.

For FF you need to use :before or :after pseudo elements to make it work. For more info go through [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content).

Answer (score 2):

According to [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content),

> The content CSS property is used with the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements to generate content in an element.

So, use `content` with pseudo elements like `:after` or `:before`(single colon is for IE8 compatibility). Something like this:

```
#Banner:after {
    content: url(../Banners/prussia-awesomeness.gif);
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Check the MDN link which I added in my post. Don't add double quotes to the url.

Comment: removed the double qoutes with no effect

Comment: @user744610 Are you sure doing like this will work? if yes, can you share the link from which you had referred so?

Comment: @user744610 Hey sorry, this is working fine in this fiddle without pseudo selector. http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/6W3dm/. Must be issue of wrong path.

Comment: the idea came from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11484688/744610 and worked fine, until we tried internet explorer and firefox. the :after suggestion made it work in firefox too. All that is left is to figure out why it still doesn't work in ie

Comment: @user744610 you may need to add `#Banner:after, #Banner:before{}`

Comment: http://imgur.com/Mdav0Dk,q9sL1AR,McAgn9S#0 this is what i got in the fiddle (tried all browsers) could this be a local problem with just my browser/machine?

Comment: @user744610 what is the version of your IE? and under which mode you are running?

Comment: @user744610 [Just saying] you can also use `background-image` instead of `content` property.

Comment: Version 10.0.9200.16635 not sure what you mean with mode i'm running?

Comment: @user744610 I mean is it standard mode or quirks mode? this quite happens when you don't mention `Doctype` at the beginning of the html markup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to removing the double quotes to a content value

```
#Banner:after {
    content: url(../Banners/prussia-awesomeness.gif);
    width: 1000px;
}
```