# Change an image using only CSS.

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have something like

```
<a href="OnlyThisONE"
 <img class="SameClassForAllIMG" src="random.png"> 
</a>
```

I would like to replace the image which something else using only CSS. Is this possible?

Here is the Javascript solution.

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
    if (images[i].src == "random.png")
        images[i].src = 'new.png';
}
```

Here is a possible CSS solution

```
.SameClassForAllIMG {
  background: url(new.png) no-repeat;
}
```

The issue is the CSS should do it for the IMG only under the "OnlyThisONE" href, and not all of them. Is this possible using only CSS?

Comment: IMO, What you do with CSS is hiding one image and displaying another one instead.

Comment: It wouldn't be random though, unless you used a preprocessor

Comment: As combination of the possible answers http://jsfiddle.net/DZRzL/1/

Comment: @Sten changing the background is not the same as changing the 'src' attribute. You can use the CSS 'content' property. I've added an example below.

Comment: in CSS you cannot change the source, so the background or a pseudo-element looks like being the right options for a CSS ONLY solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using only CSS. You can target the image using `a[href='OnlyThisONE']` and hide the `<img>` tag within, then apply a background to the `<a>` link.

**CSS**

```
a[href='OnlyThisONE'] img {
    display: none;
}
a[href='OnlyThisONE'] {
    background: url('somebackground.jpg');
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches you could use. In my opinion, the best one is #1, as it has the broadest browser support and it avoids the use of JS.

1 - You could select just that `a` (assuming the `href` is unique), show a background image, and then hide the contained image. You'll also need to specify `width`, height`, and`display`on the`a`:

```
a[href$='OnlyThisONE'] img {
    display: none; /* hide the image that's there */
}
a[href$='OnlyThisONE'] {
    background: url(someOtherImage.jpg) /* show another image as a background */
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

2 - Use `content:url()`, but it doesn't have broad browser support
- [Is it possible to set the equivalent of a src attribute of an img tag in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/how-can-we-specify-src-attribute-of-img-tag-in-css) After running a quick self-check on support of `content:url()` I would not suggest doing this, at all. I could only get it to work in Chrome. Try it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/3BRN7/49/

```
a[href$='OnlyThisONE'] img {
    content:url("newImage.jpg");
}
```

3 - Use JavaScript as you have in your question.

Comment: @Danko Wrong. You can have width/height if you set `display:inline-block`. Also, if you specifically check support of `content:url()` you'll find it's not very good, at all.

Comment: Create a test page yourself and try it. It doesn't work for me in Firefox or in IE. If I'm missing something here, please fill me in.

Comment: My mistake my friend seems like only works for a few instances but not in this case deleteing my comments and I see you add the correct for the first option +1

Answer (score 0):

If the src is "random.png", "new.png" will be displayed.

HTML

```
<a href="#">
 <img class="SameClassForAllIMG" src="//dummyimage.com/300x100/111/fff&text=random.png">
 <span></span>
</a>

<a href="#">
 <img class="SameClassForAllIMG" src="//dummyimage.com/300x100/111/fff&text=images.png">
 <span></span>
</a>
```

CSS

```
img.SameClassForAllIMG[src*="random.png"] {
    display: none;
}
img.SameClassForAllIMG[src*="random.png"] + span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(//dummyimage.com/300x100/111/fff&text=new.png) no-repeat left top;
}
```

I guess that this code is the same as your JavaScript solution.

- IE7>= version http://jsfiddle.net/nxvm7/1/
- IE8>= version http://jsfiddle.net/nxvm7/2/

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you could use either `pseudo-element` on `<a>` or a `background-image` in `<a>` or even in `<img>`  that can only be seen on hover.

here is 2 demo

- one using a pseudo-element
- one using the img tag with a background. (no src changed).

  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jchjw

```
<p>Set background-image, and resize it to zero with padding on :hover 
<a href="#nature"><img class="a-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/120/80/nature/1"> 
</a></p>
<p>use a pseudo-element set in absolute position and overflow in a tag :
<a href="#nature3"><img class="a-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/120/80/nature/3">
</a></p>
```

```
img {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
[href="#nature"]:hover .a-img {
  height:0;
  width:0;
  padding:40px 60px;
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/120/80/nature/2);
}
[href="#nature3"] {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
[href="#nature3"]:after {
  content:url(http://lorempixel.com/120/80/nature/4);
  vertical-align:top;
  position:absolute;
}
[href="#nature3"]:hover:after {
  left:0;
}
```

**The `a:hover` + `img` background works with oldest IE** an it keeps the alt attribute useful, this would be my choice. pseudo-element :after/:before works from IE8, but  not the **::**after/***::*before  syntaxe.

theres in css of course, many other solution working  with `a` or `img`  with or without a translucide gif/png :( ....