# Change image onhover with animation jQuery CSS

Tags: jquery, css, image, hover

Hi am making my own social buttons. And I want it to change oh hover. I tried:

http://helplogger.blogspot.com/2012/05/create-rollover-image-effect-change.html

But it doesn't work. Here's the

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcmHu/237/)

```
<a href="#">
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TLGeYXo.png" />
</a>

<a href="#">
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bU0lzac.png" />
</a>
```

On the first image it is a gray and white facbook logo. I want to change when hovered into my 2nd logo, the blue facebook logo. Also as it change image, is it possible to have annimation like this:

http://ariannyceleste.com/

Please look at the footer and her social button animation. I want it to be that way. I dunno much about css and designs I work mostly in backends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use the same img tag ,set a css class and set the image dynamically on moose hover from your css file.

So, if you have a class named : 
.NormalImg{--with your attributes--}
Create another element for the same class as
.NormalImg: hover {--with your attributes--}

Hope I helped

Comment: Thanks for giving me idea, I checked on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/is-it-possible-to-set-the-equivalent-of-a-src-attribute-of-an-img-tag-in-css I'll choose this as answer when the time ends.