# css height:auto not showing for responsive image

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I want create a responsive image in my doc.

```
<style>
img,.img {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div>
        <img src="img/tools3/2.png" />
    </div>
<body>
```

Now I try convert img to div:

```
<body>
        <div>
            <div class="img" style="img/tools3/2.png"></div>
        </div>
<body>
```

But not showing any images!

If I change `height: auto;` to `height: 100px;` it works but it's not responsive else...

Also I add:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
clear: both;
```

to .img but not working.

Comment: Why are you trying to load the image in a div? If you want to do that, consider using css to make background-image: url(urlPath); But I don't think that will be responsive, the first code is best for responsive pics

Comment: Consider starting your troubleshooting here: `style="img/tools3/2.png"`, which is invalid code.

Comment: because I want change image with hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the pic in the div, you can have that in the img tag.

The img tag can be changed on hover using css

```
.img:hover {
   content:url(NEWPICPATH);
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/is-it-possible-to-set-the-equivalent-of-a-src-attribute-of-an-img-tag-in-css) for more details on changing src this way.

Answer (score 0):

To do responsive images you need to set the max-width property to 100%. Images always have to be an img tag unless you decide to use background-image on a div.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the below

```
    <div>
        <div class="img" style="img/tools3/2.png"></div>
    </div>
```

The image will not show because

you have

style as `"img/tools3/2.png"`

A div is a container that can hold an image it, it does not have a source property like an image tag that points to a link.

If you want to make the image display like a div you can simply do

```
img{
    display:block
}
```

**However you can also set a div background to te an image like this**

```
div {
  width:put your width here;
  height: put yout height here;
  background-image:url("url here");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

here is a

```css
div {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background-image:url("https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTcKiWvJ9_lKvgooA-T8VMt9BBVpex3VI-NVUkNrGhiECN3YkRdqQ");
   background-size: cover;;
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is this ....
In html ....

```
<div style="width:50%;height:50%">
        <img style="width:100%; height:100%;"  src="http://www.hdwallpaperscool.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/california-beautiful-natyre-hd-wallpapers-widescreen-cool-images.jpg" />
    </div>
```

you can give any height or width for the div.If you want you can use style in external style sheet.
I suggest you to try bootstrap.it is pretty easy.