# CSS show rollover or glow image when hovering over an image link, without depending on image size?

Tags: css, image, hyperlink, hover, glow

I have two images `normal.png` and `glow.png` and both are the same size **but I don't know what this size is**.

A normal image link would look like this:

```html
<a href='http://example.com'>
  <img src='normal.png'>
</a>
```

When hovering over the link, can I make `glow.png` appear instead of `normal.png`, i.e. like a rollover image?

I found all sorts of CSS solutions for this, using sprites or :hover background images, but they all depend on knowing the image size in advance. That doesn't apply to my situation as my images are dynamic.

I'm using HTML5.

Comment: have you tried something? it is admittable to have both the images already inside the markup?

Comment: Uhm, I'm not sure what you mean by "having both images already inside the markup"?

Comment: I mean to have two images: one hidden, one visible and switch their visibility through the :hover state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pseudo-elememt overlays would seem the ideal solution:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  margin: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
a:hover:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/140/100);
}
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href='http://example.com'>
  <img src='http://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100'>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

As this article said, you can do it like this :

```
a:hover img {
  content:url("http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/255/200/2");
}
```

[See working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8un1t36/1/)

But it's not fully compatible on every browsers.

[Is it possible to set the equivalent of a src attribute of an img tag in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/is-it-possible-to-set-the-equivalent-of-a-src-attribute-of-an-img-tag-in-css/11484688#11484688)

Comment: That's just amazing.