# CSS to change image URL

Tags: html, css

How can I use an entirely separate CSS file to change/override only the URL for the image IMAGE.png?

```
<div id="id1" class="class1">
    <div id="id2" class="class2">
        <div class="class3">
            <div id="id3">
                <a class="logo" href="http://domain.com" tabindex="-1">
                    <img src="https://IMAGE.png"></img>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: You cannot change an **inline** image src/url with CSS...you'd need javascript for that.

Comment: you can't change the src of an img tag  using css. by css  you can only change the background-image

Comment: please tell what you actually want to do so we will tel you the alternative best solution

Comment: @scaisEdge That's not entirely true. This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/is-it-possible-to-set-the-equivalent-of-a-src-attribute-of-an-img-tag-in-css. I googled this very question and found three answers not two hours ago. The answer there was use `#myImage { content: url('path/to/newimage.png') }`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set the equivalent of a src attribute of an img tag in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/is-it-possible-to-set-the-equivalent-of-a-src-attribute-of-an-img-tag-in-css)

Comment: @evolutionxbox .. i think at it but the img have no id .. and then ..

Comment: @evolutionbox: The solution you posted with this link is incompatible with many browser versions, IE10 is not supported for example and IE10 is still used by many people..

Comment: @GiftZwergrapper I know. I didn't say you were wrong, just not entirely correct. - Also, this question is a duplicate, and should be marked as such.

Answer (score 3):

If you wants to achieve it with css, do it like this (Recommended).

```css
.btn {
 display: block;
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 background: url(http://mygimptutorial.com/images/button-with-metal-ring/13.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:hover {
 background: url(http://mygimptutorial.com/images/button-with-metal-ring/8.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="id1" class="class1">
    <div id="id2" class="class2">
        <div class="class3">
            <div id="id3">
                <a class="btn" href="http://domain.com" tabindex="-1"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And with js do following.

```js
$('.logo img').hover(function(){
 $(this).attr('src','http://mygimptutorial.com/images/button-with-metal-ring/8.jpg');
},function(){
 $(this).attr('src','http://mygimptutorial.com/images/button-with-metal-ring/13.jpg');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1" class="class1">
    <div id="id2" class="class2">
        <div class="class3">
            <div id="id3">
                <a class="logo" href="http://domain.com" tabindex="-1">
                <img src="http://mygimptutorial.com/images/button-with-metal-ring/13.jpg"></img></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use content in your dark-mode class

```
darl
content:url(image.jpg);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change it with CSS, you need Javascript for that.
But if you are trying to change the image on for example hover, you could remove the img-tags and use a div instead on which you set a background-image.
In your CSS you can then create a block where you change the image on hover.

Comment: That's not entirely true... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/is-it-possible-to-set-the-equivalent-of-a-src-attribute-of-an-img-tag-in-css

Comment: @evolutionbox: The solution you posted with this link is incompatible with many browser versions, IE10 is not supported for example and IE10 is still used by many people..

Comment: Whilst it is true, like many things, that it isn't compatible in many browsers, it does show that it is possible to change the image src using only css. Making "You can't change it with CSS" mostly correct, but still not true.
- Also, this question is a duplicate, and should be marked as such.