# Content url not working on fireFox and IE

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, google-chrome, firefox

I know this question was asked before but suggested solutions are not working in my case.
I am using bootstrap and I am trying to change image url when link is active. Example:

**HTML:**

```
<a id="aClientInfo" href="#" class="list-group-item active text-center">
    <img class="img-responsive imgClientInfo" src="../Images/Reports/Claims-Info-
     Blue-New.png" />
    <br />
    Client Info 
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
#aClientInfo.active > .imgClientInfo
{
 content:url("../Images/Reports/Claims-Info-Purple-New.png");   
}
```

This solution is working perfectly on chrome browsers. But whenever I run it on IE or FireFox, the image won't change ... I have tried to implement before and after but then it won't work neither on chrome... I really can't understand how before and after can work here with active class... Any suggestions? I need a solution that could work also on safari as it is a responsive website. Thanks

Comment: can you provide with css for the rest of the html elements involved?

Comment: @Dejan.S Sorry but I did not understand what you mean

Comment: how does your css for `aClientInfo` `list-group-item` `active` `img-responsive` `imgClientInfo` look

Comment: `list-group-item` `active` `img-responsive` are native bootstrap classes, aclientInfo is just an ID that I am using it in css file when icon link is clicked (#aClientInfo.active) to change the content of the image which class is `.imgClientInfo`. `aClientInfo` and `imgClientInfo` are not defined with anything else then mentioned above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set the equivalent of a src attribute of an img tag in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/is-it-possible-to-set-the-equivalent-of-a-src-attribute-of-an-img-tag-in-css)