# Change SVG on hover does not work

Tags: css

Is this the correct [way](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qozKPW) to do it?

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://svgur.com/i/6FY.svg" alt="" class="bullet"><img src="http://svgur.com/i/6FY.svg" alt="" class="bullet"><img src="http://svgur.com/i/6FY.svg" alt="" class="bullet"><img src="http://svgur.com/i/6FY.svg" alt="" class="bullet"><img src="http://svgur.com/i/6FY.svg" alt="" class="bullet">
<img src="http://svgur.com/i/6FY.svg" alt="" class="bullet">
```

**CSS**

```
.bullet {
    width: 5em;
    padding: 0.2em;
    margin: 0.2em;
}

.bullet:hover {
    content: url('http://svgur.com/i/6F0.svg');
    width: 5em;
    padding: 0.2em;
    margin: 0.2em;
}
```

On Codepen is works, but not locally and also not if I upload it onto my own server. I uploaded it to [BitBalloon](http://youthful-liskov-f16b89.bitballoon.com/) and it also does not work.

How should I approach this? Thanks :)

Comment: don't rely on the content method it's not support in all the browser i guess

Comment: your code pen work on chrom and not on firefox

Answer (score 0):

Use the svg as background and it will work fine within all the browser. Don't rely on the `content` method as it's not supported everywhere (it won't work with Firefox)

```css
.bullet {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 0.2em;
  background-image: url(http://svgur.com/i/6FY.svg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.bullet:hover {
  background-image: url('http://svgur.com/i/6F0.svg');
}
```

```html
<span class="bullet"> </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your URL. The browser tries to load the hover image from `/css/images/bullet_closed.svg`, same location where the css file is loaded from. So it returns 404.

Add another `/` before the url

```
content: url('/images/bullet_closed.svg');
```

or add the full URL

```css
.bullet {
 width: 0.8em;
 padding: 0.2em;
    margin: 0.2em;
}

.bullet:hover {
 content: url('http://youthful-liskov-f16b89.bitballoon.com/images/bullet_closed.svg');
 width: 0.8em;
 padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://youthful-liskov-f16b89.bitballoon.com/images/bullet_open.svg" class="bullet">
<img src="http://youthful-liskov-f16b89.bitballoon.com/images/bullet_open.svg" class="bullet">
<img src="http://youthful-liskov-f16b89.bitballoon.com/images/bullet_open.svg" class="bullet">
```

---

**EDIT**

It seems this approach doesn't work with FireFox. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11484688/2408342) for more information. I suggest you move along with javascript in order to achieve this.

How ever FireFox also gives the 404 for the `bullet_closed.svg`, so follow the above guideline as well.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah... mad browsers... :( they should all have one standard.