# Replacing a text block

Tags: css, html

I have a question here
[Replacing an image (in an <img /> tag) using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142386/replacing-an-image-in-an-img-tag-using-css)

about image replacing
 and now I have another wonder about text

I have the following code

```
<div class="A">
<a class="B" href="#">Learn more</a>
</div>
```

In the media query css, I would like to not display the text anymore, what should I do in this case ?

```
.A a .B
{

}
```

Comment: what have you tried? is it acceptable to hide the element itself, or does the element need to remain visible (e.g., is there a background image applied that you want to show?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.A a.B
{
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between the a and .B, which means the css parser is looking for a .B INSIDE an  tag.

Your code should look like this:

```
.A a.B
{
    text-indent:-999em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between the `a` and `.B` this means any element with class B inside an `a` element.

I guess what you meant is `.A a.B`

```
.A a.B
{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The new way to ident is not using negative indent (since it creates a big box that is rendered by the browser and causes drop in performance) is to use the Kellum Method, see [zeldman.com](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/), like so:

```
.A a.B {
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this css code

```
.A > a.B{display:none}
.A > a.B::after{content:'this is replace text'}
```